# Generate Men of Culture

Tags: code-golf, string

This challenge is inspired by the meme [Men of Culture](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/ah-i-see-youre-a-man-of-culture-as-well).

The meme involves blanking out parts of the original caption,

> Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well.

to make it appear as if the character is saying something else.

Your challenge is to write a program that, given an input, **show how the original sentence can be blanked out** to achieve the input string.

Rules:

- Use a `-` character to represent a blanked out character.
- You must not add additional letters to achieve the input string
- You may treat string comparisons as case-insensitive
- You may ignore whitespace in string comparisions
- If no substitution is possible, output a falsy value.
- You may substitute redundant whitespace with a `-` as well, although not required.
- Where multiple solutions are possible, you may output any of them.

Test cases:

Basic:

[Example Meme 1](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/235/219/960.jpg)

```
Ah, I see you're a well.
> Ah, I see you're a --- -- ------- -- well.
```

[Example Meme 2](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/235/687/fd1.png)

```
Ah, I see well.
> Ah, I see ------ - --- -- ------- -- well.
```

Edge case 1:

```
What did you just say about me, you little
> false
```

Edge case 2 (edited):

```
*no input*
> --- - --- ------ - --- -- ------- -- -----
```

Intermediate:

[Example Meme 3](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/236/506/ca8.jpg)

```
Ah, I see you're Orwell.
> Ah, I see you're - --- o- -----r- -- well.
```

[Example Meme 4](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/350/031/a17.jpg)

```
Ah, ymca.
> Ah, - --- y----- - m-- -- c------ a- ----.
```

[Example Meme 5](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/239/678/3a7.png)

```
Ah, a manual.
> Ah, - --- ------ a man -- -u----- a- --l-.
OR: > Ah, - --- ------ a man -- -u----- a- ---l.
```

Harder:

[Example Meme 6](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/235/615/b0a.jpg)

```
tea.
> --- - --- ------ - --- -- ---t--e a- ----.
```

[Example Meme 7](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/242/298/e25.jpg)

```
eeeee
> --- - -ee -----e - --- -- ------e -- -e---
```

TL;DR: Given an input string, output a string which represents how the original string should be modified to fit the input string, by using a "-" to represent a blanked out character. If a substitution is not possible, output a falsy value.

Code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

**Edit: Clarifications**

- **Ignore whitespace in string comparisions** means you can strip away whitespace before you compare strings. For instance, the inputs `Ah, a manual` and `Ah ,      a   manual` are treated as equal. Other punctuation `, ' .` must be preserved. Similarly for output, `Ah, a manual` is equal to `Ah, amanual`.
- **substitute redundant whitespace** refers to the spaces present in the original caption. You don't need to replace them with "-", but if replacing nets you more points then go ahead.

Comment: Your "Orwell" output seems wrong: you've changed an 'f' to an 'r' in the first one.

Comment: What exactly is the "original string"? With or without the trailing `.`? How is it capitalized?

Comment: What output should `"Ah,<5 SPACES HERE>a manual."` yield?

Comment: *If a substitution is not possible, output a falsy value.* Well, requiring input validation is highly discouraged.

Comment: *You may treat string comparisons as case-insensitive* does that mean we must treat the input as case-insensitive or that we're able to take input in whatever case we want? Also, by *You may ignore whitespace in string comparisions*, do you mean we must ignore spaces? And what is "redundant whitespace"?

Comment: Do we need to have the sentence "Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well" in the source code, or can we get the user to pass it as a parameter? Also, following from @EriktheOutgolfer says, do they have to be case insensitive inputs, or can we use case sensitive?

Comment: I've edited the question for clarification.

Comment: Because it's not enforced that the comparison must be case-insensitive, can we return falsy value for Orwell?

Comment: @user202729 Yes, but if you do make it case-sensitive, make sure "orwell" works.

Comment: (By the way, I feel that your challenge has too many optional features. That's (generally) not good. At least they are not bonuses.)

Comment: (and the input/output are a bit hard to parse)

Comment: I think "input validation," if you could call it that, makes sense here @EriktheOutgolfer

Answer (score 6):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 94 bytes

```
"vAh, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.
0/i~ <r
!\:?!^:}=0={:@*:@"-"$?$~}$:@?
<>~i+0)?;>o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X6nMMUNHwVOhODVVoTK/VL0oVSFRwTcxTyE/TcG5NKekFCRQrFCempOjx2Wgn1mnYFPEpRhjZa8YZ1Vra2BbbeWgZeWgpKukYq9SV6ti5WDPZWNXl6ltoGlvbZf//z@G6flFYLMA)

Case-sensitive, doesn't ignore whitespace or punctuation and outputs an empty string if the input is invalid. If you want to try other strings, you can just modify the first line after the `"v`, as long as it doesn't contain a `"` or a null byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>58</s> <s>55</s> <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```
“¬²Ẉ,ȷCIbƝɼeỴƤ/ɓIŒ;ṫṚS⁶_ŀỤ ṂB⁾÷ƈ»Ḣ”-1ị⁼ɗ?@€xṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDaw5terirQ@fEdmfPpGNzT@5Jfbh7y7El@icnex6dZP1w5@qHO2cFP2rcFn@04eHuJQoPdzY5PWrcd3j7sY5Dux/uWPSoYa6u4cPd3Y8a95ycbu/wqGlNxcOdbf8PtwNZkf//Rys5ZugoeCoUp6YqVOaXqhelKiQq5CbmKeSnKSSX5pSUggSKFcqBztFT4tLBphqLHFwoPCOxRCElMwWkWiGrtLhEoTixUiExKb@0RCE3VQcsnJNZUpKTClKN1YL8IhQLKnOTE@EcsFNLEyGyJakQiVQQUIoFAA)

---

More readable version:

```
“Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well.”Ḣ”-1ị⁼ɗ?@€xṆ
```

String compression breakdown:

```
Ah, I{short: see}{short: you}'re a{short: man} of{long: culture} as{short: we}ll.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 117 bytes

```
^.
¶Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.¶$&
{+i`¶(\W|(\w))(.*¶)(?(2)\W*\2)
$1¶$3
}1`¶\w
-¶
.*¶.*¶.*\w.*|¶.*¶.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NCsJADIX3OUUW/sxULagHEHEhLsRlN4MYNWJl2kI7QynqteYAc7HaWsSFBgJ5Lx/v5WzilOq@WB/qfQjeLa9j3GDBjFVmhzkj4ZZSzC64strY1iiwZK1D73oDuI/ig3dCRQ@hSilFGHgnxULMpIoCNZPQmzbcHJ7TBlMlTLyDlulWlWHw@Aio6z/l7yr4PjodXcngOT63HN5sYbCgCumYWYMJj9@2jo3RDPATusu/oVVyou4iTCi11PiGG4vbeQE) Could save 1 byte by requiring case-sensitivity. Could save 3 bytes by returning `--, - --- ---'-- - --- -- ------- -- ----.` on empty input. Explanation:

```
^.
¶Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.¶$&
```

Prepend the desired text to the input.

```
{+i`¶(\W|(\w))(.*¶)(?(2)\W*\2)
$1¶$3
```

Move as many characters from the desired text to the result as possible. If the character is a letter then it also needs to match the next letter in the input, which is then deleted.

```
}1`¶\w
-¶
```

If there is no matching letter in the input, change it to a `-` and try again.

```
.*¶.*¶.*\w.*|¶.*¶.*
```

If there are still letters left in the input, delete everything, otherwise delete the remainder of the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>126</s> 114 bytes

```python
i=input()
r=''
for c in"Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well.":x=c==i[:1];r+=c*x or'-';i=i[x:]
print(i=='')*r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BbsIwEETv/oqRL4YAleDWIB848gU9IA6usyiuHDty1mry9SFJiwQSe1rNjN7stgPXMRxGGyvSUsrRaRfazKu1SFopcYsJFi7IU73FGR0RhphVIhg0JiDeYLPnPAsdfsn7D1n22mrtLuX@ekwbbYseMamdOk7sS19eRZtc4JXTU8G6SONUKwT1ZDFfUXyO78r@0OLJeihftWFUrpqz@MkdozMDzHfMjIa2i@wds6cp/EL4h8f0DB8aax778mM2i8e0yDSPvAM)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>108</s> 106 bytes

Input is a list of chars.

```python
lambda i:''.join(c==`i`[2:3]and i.pop(0)or'-'for c in"Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well.")*(i==[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9NasMwEIX3OsWgjaWSmpLuDFp02RN0kQai2DKeIEvCGlF8eleyQ0P6A9VmZt6MHu8LMw3e7ZdevS9Wj@dOAzZVVV88OtEqdcLTYd88H7XrAOvgg3iSfqoeq95P0AI6/jLs4BWiMTD7VE0GNIzage@hTZZSESJ8GGtrLh8EKnU4yoVMpAgKOP/t/3rNbottfhs0QYdduYNLigRRz6DPPhGMZrfKFomsYeyHqZ9upvPY6q1boyaddTJZMuXlSHUM2ciiM1FIxgpqCZxp1xobBhAmdAS9sBhJFFXK5U8Wzvg3mqz8nycf3zncM11XK9W1/@LKcyHLZWP7BA)

Comment: Could `(i=='')` not be `(i<' ')` (using a tab, the lowest printable character)?

Comment: @JonathanFrech this is possible, but it is both 7 bytes

Comment: Well, you have got a point there ...

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 135 bytes

```javascript
x=>!!x&&(t="Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.".replace(/./g,c=>c>' '?/^(.)\1/i.test(c+x)?(x=x.slice(1).trim(),c):'-':c),!x&&t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RCoIwFEB/5eqD2yWd@GpMiUDooT@IYKybLZYTN2t9vSW99Ho4cM5dPZXXkxlDMbgLLZ1comySJGYZDzLd3XI4gCeCt5vZRKDgqAZwV9jPNswr8PAia0UqJhqt0sRLUfa5lo1uGLC2PHOBp6o0IpAPXG8itjzKKLw1X7lCESbz4JhrrFnBao35Gg@4bLUbvLMkrOt5x/9efkHE5QM)

If "may" mean either do or not do is okay, then

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 106 bytes

```javascript
x=>x&&(t="Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.".replace(/./g,c=>c==x[0]?(x=x.slice(1),c):'-'),!x&&t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCsIwEAC/snpoE0hTvSpbEaHgwReIhxDXWgndkqQaXx8rHr3OwMzDPE2wvh9jNfCVcos5YZOKQkRc7u8KjhCI4M1T6QkMnMwAfIPD5OL0BQFe5Jxeak@jM5ZEretOWWwsYjqvLjuRMOng@lmtpbJyU1alVIv5EGXeWh4CO9KOO9GK/yH7X17K/AE)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>122</strike> 120 bytes

```javascript
x=>"Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.".replace(/./g,c=>c>' '?/^(.)\1/i.test(c+x)?(x=x.slice(1).trim``,c):'-':c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsIwEAC/svSSBNuEXgupSE8e/IFIw7rWSGxKkmp8fVS8eh0GZm7mYSIGu6Rm9mcqgy5Z99XuWsMeIhG8/MoCgYGDmcFfYFhdWr8gwpOck5UMtDiDxJVUU426x54B26oTl@LYKisTxcRxk8WWZ51ldPYjt0KmYO/jWKPoWMM6FAX9HL0j6fzEB/7v4VcUorwB)

## Explanation :

```javascript
x =>                 // It takes in 'x' as parameter for function a string
    "Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.". // What the actual is 
            .replace(                             // Now we are gonna replace 
                    /./g,     // selects everything 
                    c =>      // lambda function with param c
                        c > ' ' ?                 
                        /^(.)\1/i.test(           // does it all
                            c + x ) ?            // checks if there is a match
                            (x=x.slice(1). // returns everything from 1 to end in an array
                                trim`` ,   // removes whitespaces
                            c : '-' : c)   // and done
```

---

Can be reduced further but replaces whitespaces with '-' as well. If this is acceptable then

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 112 bytes

```javascript
x=>"Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.".replace(/./g,c=>/^(.)\1/i.test(c+x)?(x=x.slice(1).trim``,c):'-')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1BCsIwEEDRqwzdNMF2QrdCFOnKhTcQaYhjjYxNSVKNp4@KW7efD@9mHiba4ObUTv5Mpdcl6021uzawh0gEL7/UgcDAwUzgL9AvnJZviPAkZqww0MzGklCoxsbqjToJlMdOOUwUk7CrLLci64yR3WfrJKbg7sPQWLmu21oW66fomZD9KHrxz/5JUpY3)

Reduced even further , only replaces whitespaces that are after the given string with '-'.

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 105 bytes

```javascript
x=>"Ah, I see you're a Man of Culture as well.".replace(/./g,c=>/^(.)\1/i.test(c+x)?(x=x.slice(1),c):'-')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1BCsIwEEDRqwzdNIPthG6FVKQrF95AhBDHWhmS0qQaTx8Vt24/H97dPmx0yzSn1ocLl8GUbPpqf2vgAJEZXmGtFwYLR@shXGFYJa3fEOHJIlTRwrNYx0qTHhtnen1WhKdOT5Q4JuU2GXcqm0xRps/WYeNwW7c1Fhd8DMIkYVSD@of@CMTyBg)

Comment: Don't pass `What did you just say about me, you little`

Comment: I'm not getting correct output for your code for the `What did you just say about me, you little` test case. Your program produces `--- - --- ------ - --- -- ------- -- w----` as output which is not what the challenge spec requires.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>182</strike> <strike>174</strike> <strike>172</strike> <strike>171</strike> <strike>170</strike> 169 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
t=toLower
a!b=(b:)<$>a
""%l=Just$'-'<$l
l@(a:b)%(c:d)|t a==t c=b%d!c|1>0=l%d!'-'
_%_=mempty
(%"Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well.").concat.words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BS8QwEIXv@RWzoaUtrEWvZbMoelEEjx6XaRK31aQpyZRS2P9e0wqyy@qcZj7ezJvXYPjSxsxza3vnCZ6QsHxs0DMS5F7dqD3DTS3yuip2yR4Z56kRL0OgJLvJdolh5j7Hqi7SXFaqOBGgEARS1KnayNPd/laY2EUtO6QHYbXtaWJHkaf8odnCMwStYXJD5jUgWOzAfYAcDA0LCDDG50pelNJ1EqkcnVdhtth2IEA5BrGMJujj2Pu2IyjhuNIe/jL4OXctuOTvDRKoVi178BmzQsAJsHYDgdXbFZuWyOjfFf6v6Zu/Np2sxEuyZh/wTEf6TKKX4vM3)

Ungolfed:

```hs
import Data.Char

template = "Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well."

-- strip spaces
preprocess :: String -> String
preprocess = filter (/=' ')

-- case-insensitive character comparison
a#b = (toLower a) == (toLower b)

strike' :: String -> String -> Maybe String
strike' "" "" = Just ""  -- base case
strike' _ "" = Nothing   -- chars are exhausted, impossible to convert
strike' "" rem = Just $ '-' <$ rem  -- full match, strike rest of chars
strike' cur@(x:xs) (r:rs)
    | x # r     =   (r:) <$> strike' xs rs  -- character matches; pop a char
    | otherwise = ('-':) <$> strike' cur rs -- no match; strike char, don't pop

strike :: String -> Maybe String
strike xs = strike' (preprocess xs) template
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>764</s> 600 bytes

```
(((<>)))([]((((((([][][]()){}[]){})[][]){}))[[]()])[][]())([[]](([][](([][]){})[]){}())[[]])(([()()][]([[]]([()]([[]](((([()][][][])[]){}[]())[])[]))()()()))[[]])((([[][][]]((([](([()()()][]){})){})(()()()()){}())[[]])[]){})((((()((([][]){}())((()()()){}){})[[][][]]))){}{}())((()(((([]()()()())())){}{}()())[[][]]){}[])(([(()()()){}](((((()()()()){}[]))){}{}))((()()){}()){})(([()][][]([()()()][])))(((([][][]())[([]()()){}()])[]())[[]])([[]]((([]()())(()()()()){}){})()()()){([{}]<>({})){(<{}(((((()()()()())){}{})){}{})>)}{}(<({}<(<()>)<>{({}<>)<>}>{})>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}<>}{}<>{{{}}<>}<>{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFBDgIxCPzOcNAXNP1Iw2E1mhiNB@Ot2bdXGNpu3WbZAsMwsJfP9nif7q/t2RqAlEUERRFPUT8QqXtRM@Kuf6V4WKWnYa4GPGxgzYJQFQtDrMIAxJrXb2BKo1UUkTMcAc9k8Ro/SnWdleWUZS8wao7ukeVIgqnQhWNiKbmTiwcOQPQatJjZoHc89@NqJl1f4aGlDNbRNRRQ11jAOo7I3x8oXQKrfKK52TK3QXVLS5J3B8U0pQxuCclYVn2Y2miz@HzJwMmsuSlXd/yyZwLWiH9paq2739dkyq19b9u5na4/)

Big improvements thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king), especially in the string construction but also a few logical tweaks in the main body. [Explanation from him](https://tio.run/##VVHBjqMwDL3zFZZ6caRhvwBxn9tqtdIeEIeUmiVql3STdOaA@u2M7UDKNKoh9vN7z@YcrJvr8Wav64qITWuMwa7H/Ot6OWjM8ux6Dkau8jSdpHuzlZGvfYbnmLEcUaG94TQa7mCAYvm2vaGW@iyVm5QzXwzqKSzSI6dXdxurtqst/iPuPS/1XNWRDBaHYhwLVi1v5EYSL0DW2mmxVDO94HU/4qbQbSt8eel21l01O1Bf@wKO4xjz7Qt0mwXtkonKZruyDXV3kFTyfIHTz0ecIKbg5r9VtcDpz@RutCcAsGPPTYvibwNf3DhSoHkgOFP6JJoh@Tv4Edx8fySw82VPZBrwc/JbMSY7XN/gU1XugSKFD4FolfUWbHiS446w7EdjazgCnN5HGCYb7JAoRLCBYPYJ6P/D3t7gLj5rsd@w84Yj9zXtIhd5ebbKdMzIk2l/2yt9H0cdA5JLEwWowQcYXYhJ5QvM6Niqy7OefUr@32EDSlKxSMWay/JksSevk3UYOuVyBLdrugg3GhP4DwrV0SV7PP0izkYC/0iMXddE9sdaX9Z6@AI)

It's case-sensitive (so "Ah, I see you're Orwell." doesn't match but "Ah, I see you're orwell." does), whitespace in input is *not* ignored, and unmatched whitespace in original string is converted to `-`. By my understanding, all of those are valid options.

Explanation:

```
(476 bytes of much improved stack manipulation) #Push string

{ #While string
  ([{}]<>({})) #Check whether the top characters are equal
  {(<{}(((((()()()()())){}{})){}{})>)}{}  #If characters are not equal, push - on top of input
  (<({}<(<()>)<>{({}<>)<>}>{})>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}<>  #Take top of input (either - or matched char) and add to output
}{}
<>{{{}}<>} #Pop both stacks if input is left over
<>{({}<>)<>}<> #Reverse output
```

Comment: You know, there was a [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157539/text-to-brain-flak) earlier to help automate producing arbitrary test for Brain-Flak. My own submission can (with a couple of modifications) get the text down to [506 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVLLagMxDPwdzWH7BUI/YnzYlgZCQg@lN@Nvd/WwvCZks5Flz2hGFvv5e95/jtvzfIxBLKDrAQGtvwRQqaVaoi@KbaoCVAg1EfJjA0jZ5BVerLAtLjVZ1RgluJNJUyxNnG4K5uM/GMHWTSVMajZ/SUxvEGV1COZF6qXubPj5GsEE9tY3LBBamKPrvng3y6WkLSwRN8Q@5nWFqYYY5uYVnFUV3BxQZBU520S87LqWW2nCQqQpS7HFukEzf2L32oeRDcwosNiUxCyts/iBqrCZgltsRLVt34MS/6aIuXAyJHAPram3dPsodTfG3/f5MY6vfw)

Comment: With a couple of other improvements, I got the total down to [604 bytes](https://tio.run/##TVFLrsMwCLzOsGhPYPkiyIu0aqWqT29RdWfl7O7wseVYIQaGGSC3z/H6vzz/jvcYAEoVEWhDPNrsQKSf2mjEXPuKWrhJpqFIWIuisFFBC2MlSFjDJItTQT3gWAc6C2/wI5aed5OkA9dKNaa9y@R2Mm@PLzArQz8y22ARBxbK241ujN5CExIqkxArB4mKtaPk37QZDDSnWcGWutGD9zVXsY8S2usvaDYRk0vEfCu50Uzv8k6eDpTKpcI3hEKWvdc5VdoqNmEhuNDSLbWbY5ezOmCP2NdN7/20@54sdYzv47iOy/0H)

Comment: [Explanation](https://tio.run/##VVFBbuMwDLz7FQRyoYBmX2D4vrdFUaAHwwfFpddCUiuVlPZg5O1eipQMb4zQEjmcGdKXYN1ynm72um2I2HbGGOwH1F8/5AeNWZ/9wMHka36bPqcHU8rYY4EN2qRROzhiZmWQ4R4ucnNR6CUhWAEKC59QHpPL9Zwl@YKiVdS4LC4Lt5CJPf4j1k7V18phMM0j7iixq24yfU5ViKpUQtxraLRj31HhP2hzUtE8zZ4ciq56EF91FcdRVHv/Cn0xoZMbzclWykZL@Sgv5HqB059HnCGm4Ja/TbPC6X12N6oJAOzZWdth3mABf7hpokDLSHCh9EO0QPJ38BO45f5IYJePmlAa8EvypRiTHa8v8CMq90CRwneGSJX1Vmx5kuO@6mZL7AxHgNPvCcbZBjsmChFsIFh8Avp62NsL3LPPc7bfsvOWI/e13Zov@fDshOmYyW@mfbNX@n8ccQxILs0U4Aw@wORCTCK/w4yMLbo868Wn5D8PGxCShkUa1lzXJ4s9eZ2sw9BZyxFc1XQRbjQl8N8UmqNL9nh6Jc5GAv9IjN22RPbXdh7/AQ)

Comment: [A nice and round 600 bytes](https://tio.run/##VVFBDgIxCPzOcNAXNP1Iw2E1mhiNB@Ot2bdXGNpu3WbZAsMwsJfP9nif7q/t2RqAlEUERRFPUT8QqXtRM@Kuf6V4WKWnYa4GPGxgzYJQFQtDrMIAxJrXb2BKo1UUkTMcAc9k8Ro/SnWdleWUZS8wao7ukeVIgqnQhWNiKbmTiwcOQPQatJjZoHc89@NqJl1f4aGlDNbRNRRQ11jAOo7I3x8oXQKrfKK52TK3QXVLS5J3B8U0pQxuCclYVn2Y2miz@HzJwMmsuSlXd/yyZwLWiH9paq2739dkyq19b9u5na4/)

Comment: @JoKing you're very good at improving my Brain-Flak it seems

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 109 bytes

```
[]+[]+[].
I+[B|X]+[C|O]:-(I=[B|J],B=C;I=J,C=45),J+X+O.
I-O:-I+`Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well.`+O.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLboMwELzzFXsrFjan9kJEpYQTXMitVAgVNziJK4MjP4qQ8u/UQKumKas97M7O7EhzUVLIE9E9H8eyCuYOvTQod9fCzck1ryLip7Hbswrv4mSTxhlO4scnhLOgCHJHJnlE0qDenjGkoBmDQdoHxYBCSzuQRzhYYewEaOiZEGHtZGOj@CdTfoqcmOzJszaKd6e3g2yY9nO8R7hX3DDR@Tna/IxHKjRDoRcRKOLSg7nWnBcf/J9xd3g5UwMNbyYlfFhtQNMB6Lu0BlqGZ1hwYwT71ay9/TaWasV4aA/0DpqjsfSWadgtiU1VL1s1oy29CK6Nv@SGC4Q7EY711rl2co54SbcmBf6T5avjhp73BQ)

Case-sensitive and whitespace sensitive. The `-/2` predicate is the main predicate with its first argument being the input string and the second argument being the output string.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (Node.js), 103 bytes

```javascript
s=>!s[i=0,r="Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well.".replace(/./g,c=>c==s[i]&&++i||c-1?c:'-'),i]&&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxcsMgDED3fIWSITYXTJo1OdzrmC/o0OtAsZyQw@CCaOtr@u2ucYYMrSbpSbwTuqgPFXUwPVXONzi2coyyXsYXIx94kKunM4cjREQYfCoCgoJOOfAt6GQpZRDhE60VKxGwt0pjuRXbE9ey1lJOntf1erMx16uudo96X1QF45mFMeB7MgHLyaoaaxwWTOgpJzw6wtBm1TcY1yfaQx@8xhhFpMY4@GHCu7KYH3Eg/CKQNWjvorcorD@VbZkpY@ww/vOFeeHFvXGrn8@KoDFNnoNLigRRDaDefCLokM/YGiKLiz9OH@7OodPqls3HSmrihBPCHL8)

Case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 78 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```
V." y°äz ÂµÿéiSs¾ýØC[ócõ!ó5§n"=b.x@zZkIqbN=+kN=hZ.?=+k\-))I<Zlz!z.?k
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V.%22+y%C2%97%C2%B0%C3%A4z+%C3%82%C2%B5%C3%BF%C3%A9%C2%92iSs%C2%92%C2%94%C2%BE%C3%BD%7F%C3%98C%C2%98%C2%89%5B%C3%B3c%07%C3%B5%11%21%C3%B35%13%C2%A7n%22%3Db.x%40zZkIqbN%3D%2BkN%3DhZ.%3F%3D%2Bk%5C-%29%29I%3CZlz%21z.%3Fk&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Ah%2C+I+see+you%27re+a+well.%0AAh%2C+I+see+well.%0AWhat+did+you+just+say+about+me%2C+you+little%0A%0AAh%2C+I+see+you%27re+Orwell.%0AAh%2C+I+see+you%27re+orwell.%0AAh%2C+ymca.%0AAh%2C+a+manual.%0Atea.%0Aeeeee%0AAh+%2C++++++a+++manual%0AAh%2C+amanual&debug=0)
<sup>Unprintable characters present in code, see link for correct version.</sup>
*Case sensitive, does not ignore whitespace.*

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-F`, 192 bytes

```perl
@q="Ah, I see you're a man of culture as well."=~/./g;while($x=shift@F){$x=~/\w/||next;while($_=shift@q){push@r,/\W/?$_:/\Q$x/i?$_:'-';$r[-1]=~/\w/i&&last}@q||last}say!$x&&@r,map/\w/?'-':$_,@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5NC4IwAIb/yoqhCery0EUR10XoENGpQ4aMmDmYX9tEI@unt7SPU7eHl@d9eWsq@Epr3ITzdW6DDZCUgmvVmoICAgpSgioD55ardgok6Cjn7jx8IBddgi5nnC5gH8qcZQrH1m3kB0o6NAwl7dVPSL9CY93qVuZY2Cg5oAimPkr2sEdsQtMxAyiOjnf6TDDD4ESqO26G4Q2SXGewN4yxXpB6UqKx48PUxo3Wf@93oqPPqlasKqV2Yu1sV663dJcv)