# Numbers by Position

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

**Challenge**

Print the numbers:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

In that order.

**I/O**

Takes no input. The numbers can have any delimiters desired (or none). That includes lists, cell arrays, .jpeg, etc.... Example outputs:

```
122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999

[1,22,333,4444,55555,666666,7777777,88888888,999999999]

etc....
```

**Code Example**

This is an un-golfed example that may perhaps act as algorithm guide (or maybe not):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 535 bytes

```
0 * 1 r L
L * _ r 2
2 * 2 r a
a * 2 r M
M * _ r 3
3 * 3 r b
b * 3 r c
c * 3 r N
N * _ r 4
4 * 4 r d
d * 4 r e
e * 4 r f
f * 4 r O
O * _ r 5
5 * 5 r g
g * 5 r h
h * 5 r i 
i * 5 r j
j * 5 r P
P * _ r 6
6 * 6 r k
k * 6 r l
l * 6 r m
m * 6 r n
n * 6 r o
o * 6 r Q
Q * _ r 7
7 * 7 r p
p * 7 r q
q * 7 r r
r * 7 r s
s * 7 r t
t * 7 r u
u * 7 r R
R * _ r 8
8 * 8 r v
v * 8 r w
w * 8 r x
x * 8 r y
y * 8 r z
z * 8 r A
A * 8 r B
B * 8 r S
S * _ r 9
9 * 9 r C
C * 9 r D
D * 9 r E
E * 9 r F
F * 9 r G
G * 9 r H
H * 9 r I
I * 9 r J
J * 9 r halt
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?af86c0ef679234d7861085b48ba90983)

This prints out the numbers with a space delimiter:

```
1 22 333 4444 55555 666666 7777777 88888888 999999999
```

**Challenge Type**

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes (by language) wins.

*Based on a [submission in the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/18658#18658).*

Comment: Can the delimeters be numbers?

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter, No. Good catch. **Edit:** Actually, I think '0' should be acceptable.

Comment: Could you verify that they "strange delimiters" version of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201222/56656), is valid?  It definitely seems cheaty.

Comment: Honestly I think it's a clever 'outside-of-the-box' solution. I'd upvote, but I'm out of votes until tomorrow.

Comment: Is `[1,2,2,3,3,3...]` a valid output? What about the same but as a list of characters? Does it matter if the language displays lists of characters as a string or as a list? What about `[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],...]` or the character version of it?

Comment: @xnor, All looks fine to me. I thought I'd sort of implied that lists were ok with one of my example outputs. But to make it clear, yes, Output of lists of characters are entirely acceptable.

Comment: @ouflak Thanks for the algorithm guide! How did you know I always write my prototypes with Turing Machines :p

Comment: Is a leading empty list in the output allowed?

Comment: @Razetime, Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 194 bytes

```
{{i}ddddd}dc{d}{d}iiic{i}{i}ddcc{d}{d}iic{i}{i}dccc{d}{d}ic{i}{i}cccc{d}{d}c{i}{i}iccccc{d}{d}dc{i}{i}iicccccc{d}{d}ddc{i}{i}iiiccccccc{d}{d}dddc{i}{i}iiiicccccccc{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}iiiiiccccccccc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tck5DoAwEEPRE3EoZINwTTnK2YcAs8Ry9T6Pnafua3M30@C7QRjHvCRM/BxlSSgKQUmA0MS0H1ObwyssJVO3NVaF@wM)

Comment: Understandable.

Comment: @lyxal ???? (filler)

Comment: @wasif the reason it was accepted

Comment: [159 bytes](https://tio.run/##RclBEsAgCEPRE/VQTtJOWbtkPDtWCZYV74d342P9vSLc1g3CyfF98CVCTkLcgrRhKDKdIUslNcVTK1f/h7MgYgI "Deadfish~ – Try It Online"), and [128](https://tio.run/##TYxBDoBACANf5KNMq5GzR7JvR1o0sZd2hgQeO8@4r60qQ1kEEQFQ1d3DS1N7wGR8ecQYIvtP1yS5dLfD31l9BlUP "Deadfish~ – Try It Online") separating by zeros.

Comment: Actually, [61](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f@/OhMEalOSM5NBCIwhBJSEUXAawUj@/x8A "Deadfish~ – Try It Online") since delimiters aren't even required.

Comment: @Steffan Go post that yourself, this was probably metagolfed

Answer (score 29):

## Google Sheets, 35 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(Rept(Row(1:9),Row(1:9
```

Sheets will automatically add three trailing parentheses when you exit the cell. Output is one line per row.

[image: results]

Comment: I've run out of votes.

Comment: @ouflak Darn...

Answer (score 16):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, <s>27</s>, 25 bytes

```bash
seq -f8d%f*7-v1+2/n 45|dc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEE3zSJFNU3LXLfMUNtIP0/BxLQmJfn/fwA)

---

*Changed seq formatting from %0.f to %f for a 2-byte savings.*

*Modified to print on one line, with no delimiters, instead of having a newline after each number, just because I like that better.  Same number of bytes.*

---

This uses the formula $$\left\lfloor\frac{\big\lfloor\sqrt{8n-7}\big\rfloor+1}2\right\rfloor$$

for the \$n^{th}\$ digit, where \$n\$ goes from 1 to 45.

Answer (score 16):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
9L×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0ufw9P//AQ)

```
9L    Build a list from 1 to 9 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
×     copy each number that many times
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
i=1;exec"print`i`*i;i+=1;"*9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PW0Dq1IjVZqaAoM68kITNBK9M6UxsoqKRl@f8/AA)

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 6 bytes

Full program, requiring `⎕IO←0`.

```apl
⍋⍛⌿⍨⎕D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/qG@qp/@jtgkGXEAWkNb4/6i3@1Hv7Ec9@x/1rgCKufzX/A8A)

`⎕D` on the string "0123456789",

`⍛⌿⍨` replicate the characters by

`⍋` their grade (0, 1, 2, …, 9)

Comment: Isn't `\⍨⍳9` at **4 bytes** sufficient? I've added it as my own answer, though it doesn't seem to be gaining any traction. Would love feedback!

Comment: @AviF.S. It wasn't clear that this was a permitted format, but now that OP has clarified, you have my upvote.

Answer (score 9):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 30 bytes

```
{(1..9).map{"$it".repeat(it)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxDoAgDADArzTEoR0kcdSIL3DzBQxiGgGJVhfC25Hb77zEc6yf9eAmQIJ@gZUfmTe5OR4LmJpx0HokHWzKqmNR@t7TbgVZqJTq3gjBcmzXQGpJ0CFR/QE)

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 18 bytes

```r
a=1:9;(10^a-1)/9*a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9HW0MrSWsPQIC5R11BT31Ir8f9/AA)

Use the formula \$\frac{10^n-1}{9}\times n\$ for the \$n\$th number.

Comment: Hmm, I may be out of date but isn't the usual ruling that it needs cat() or equivalent to print the output?

Comment: @user2390246 yeah, the consensus was changed...a while ago? Late 2017 by my quick search of meta. [This is probably what you're aware of](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-should-a-full-program-in-r-be-invoked/13744#13744) but taking that approach with [this meta post on compiler flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339) basically means all R answers are just "R invoked with `source(...,echo=TRUE)`"

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks for the clarification, I've not been around for a while! Seems like the trend for cat()-type answers ended up being quite a short phase then.

Comment: Beat you with a [string-only approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201242/67312)! :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe Ooh, nice!

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

```
\⍨⍳9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBDGPelc86t1sCQA)

#### How it works

```
⍳9        ⍝ Integers 1..9
   ⍨      ⍝ Duplicate argument on each side
     \    ⍝ Replicate each element *n* times
```

#### Examples

```
Index Generator:    ⍳5          =  1 2 3 4 5
Expand:             2 3 \ 1 4   =  1 1 4 4 4
Commute:            +⍨4         =  4 + 4 = 8
```

Comment: Feedback: I'd use `/⍨⍳9` as it is simpler. `/` is really "replicate" while ``\`` is the more complex "expand".

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 18 bytes

```perl
map{say$_ x$_}1..9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saC6OLFSJV6hQiW@1lBPz/L//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 6):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 56 bytes

```
+++++++[>+++++++<-]+++++++++[<+[>>.<<-<+>]<[>+<-]>>>+<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwKi7aAMG91YbRiItgGK2@nZ2OjaaNvF2gDVAGXt7MDU//8A)

```
+++++++[>+++++++<-]     49 (ASCII "1")
+++++++++[              do 9 times
  <+                    add 1 to output counter
  [                     do that many times
    >>.<<               print character
    -<+>                move value of output counter to temp
  ]
  <[>+<-]               move value of temp back to output counter
  >>>+                  increment character
  <-                    decrement loop counter
]
```

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fOzraRttO104bBGxi7bRjbWx0dW10o@3stKNt9EAyQFGwGqCMto1u7P//AA)

Comment: Thank you. Your code is so different from mine, you should post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 12 bytes

```
9*

$.`*$.`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8tSi4tLRS9BC4j//wcA) Outputs a leading `_` to each number, which appears to be acceptable (would cost 2 bytes to fix if not). Explanation:

```
9*
```

Insert 9 `_`s.

```
$.`*$.`
```

Around each `_`, insert its position repeated appropriately.

Comment: The leading `_` is absolutely acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```hs
(<$)<*>g<$>g '9'
g c=['1'..c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX8NGRdNGyy7dRsUuXUHdUp0rXSHZNlrdUF1PLzn2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiUKawv9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
⎕D/⍨⍳10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGIJaL/qPeFY96Nxsa/E8Dij3q7YNIdzUfWm/8qG0ikBcc5AwkQzw8g/@nAQA)

Uses `⎕IO←0`.

#### How it works

```apl
⎕D/⍨⍳10
⎕D       ⍝ The string '0123456789'
  /⍨     ⍝ Replicate each of them the following times...
    ⍳10  ⍝ 0..9
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>90</s> 82 bytes

```
([(()()())({}){}]){((({})()<([{}]((((()()()){}){}){}){})>)<{({}()<(({}))>)}{}>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fI1pDQxMENTWqazWra2M1qzU0QEwNTRuNaCBfAwQgKsAKoMhO06YaqAykCqQayK@trgUT////13UEAA)

### Explanation:

---

Compare this with the output of [JoKing's autogolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157666/56656)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 142 bytes

```
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}())()))())))()))))())))))()))))))())))))))()))))))))()))))))))){({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fg2SgCYKa1bVwBOQBERhDCCgJo@A0goHE0qzWqK61sdO0sQOS////13UEAA)

---

## Strange delimiters, 78 bytes

```
([(()()())({}){}]){((({})()<([{}]((((()()()){}){}){}){})>)<{({}()<(({}))>)}>)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fI1pDQxMENTWqazWra2M1qzU0QEwNTRuNaCBfAwQgKsAKoMhO06YaqAykCqQayK8Fov///@s6AgA)

If we decide to play around with our delimiters a bit, we can shave off 4 bytes.  This version outputs the correct stuff but with two leading null bytes and null bytes between the chunks:

This is a tiny bit cheaty but it meets the specs of the challenge.

---

And for posterity [here](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwI0QVCzuhaOgLxoDQ0IL1azGsTU0LQBi0RrAEXsNG2qkcSA/Fo7IF37//9/XUcA) is the old super cheaty version that has been made obsolete by my golfs.

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
d´Ṙḣ9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@XQloc7Zzzcsdjy/38A)

Output: `122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
echo u:(#48+])i.10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1@h1EpD2cRCO1YzU8/Q4P9/AA)

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>11</s> 10  bytes

-1 byte thanks to ngn!

```
,/${x}#!10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0dfpbqiVlnR0OD/fwA)

Comment: `,/${x}#!10` - using filter (`{` `}#`) for replication

Comment: @ngn Thanks, of course!

Comment: I think `echo#~1+i.10` is ok too since any delimiter is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
9ẋ`€Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/y4a7uhEdNax7u6Pn/HwA)

A niladic link returning a list of integers. If a program printing the numbers is preferred, subsitute `Y` for `Ḍ`.

### Explanation

```
9     | Literal 9
 ẋ`€  | Repeat each that many times
    Ḍ | Convert from decimal digits to integer
```

Comment: You can drop the trailing `Ḍ`, based on the comments below the challenge description between _xnor_ and OP.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 13 bytes

```perl6
{1..9 Zx^9+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X5xYqaDxv9pQT89SIaoizlLbsPa/pobmfwA)

Anonymous code block that returns a list of strings by zip string multiplying the range 1 to 9 with itself.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java 11 (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>60</s> 59 bytes

Not sure if thats the shortest approach but couldn`t make it shorter even without System.out.print.
Output is without delimiters.

*-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```java
v->{for(int i=0;i++<9;System.out.print((i+"").repeat(i)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwEETvfMXG0zaExqup@AdyIfFiPNRSSLEU0pYaQ/j2WtDLTnY3M/N6HnjRN68oNHcOrlyZJQNQxkvbciGh2laAMKoGBN42CYSl25qlUYGBMobisrSjxeQCVR6ZyvPzidUf5@VAx9nTyaYXosoPB0KtnCT3qAghbI1b1DQ/tRLgPPdJ9qohgWDtk6@7P4DbzpEfiJHvnRIJNVSgmbX@46zxCw)

Comment: You can [save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwEETvfMXG0zaExqup@AdyIfFiPNRSSLEU0pYaQ/j2WtDLTnY3M/N6HnjRN68oNHcOrlyZJQNQxkvbciGh2laAMKoGBN42CYSl25qlUYGBMobisrSjxeQCVR6ZyvPzidUf5@VAx9nTyaYXosoPB0KtnCT3qAghbI1b1DQ/tRLgPPdJ9qohgWDtk6@7P4DbzpEfiJHvnRIJNVSgmbX@46zxCw) changing the `()->` to `v->`, by taking an empty unused (`Void null`) argument, [which is allowed when it's completely unused](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding).

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen Thanks for the suggestion, didn't know about that. I now use an Object as parameter and pass null, is this the intended way or can you actually do it with Void?

Comment: `Object null` is fine as well. As long as the argument isn't used in any way, not even for static calls, it's ok. That's why I personally use `Void`, since it has no available static calls anyway. :)

Comment: Well thats awkward, could've sworn that it just didn't compile with type `Void`, changed it again and now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 46 bytes

```c
s;main(n){n>9||main(puts(memset(&s,n+48,n)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/YOjcxM08jT7M6z86ypgbMKSgtKdbITc0tTi3RUCvWydM2sdDJ09TUtK79/x8A)

Comment: can't be called twice

Comment: Thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

```hs
[c<$[1..c]|c<-[1..9]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfbhvzPzrZRiXaUE8vObYm2UYXxLKMjf2fm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeikP7/X3JaTmJ68X/d5IICAA)

A list of lists of numbers.

**23 bytes**

```hs
replicate<*>id=<<[1..9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfbhvzvyi1ICczObEk1UbLLjPF1sYm2lBPzzL2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiUL6/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

A flat list of numbers.

Comment: I think that the delimiter has to be in between differing digits (e.g. `1` and `2` as opposed to `8` and another `8`).

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Looking again at the challenge, I'm not clear on this so I asked. I think it would be unfortunate if the flat list in the second version were invalid too.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 15 bytes

```r
strrep(1:9,1:9)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikqCi1QMPQylIHiDX//wcA)

Comment: Just ```rep(1:9,1:9)``` is shorter (and gives exactly the output of the first example)?

Answer (score 4):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>18</del> 16 bytes

**Binary**:

```
00000000: b839 0ab2 09b1 2dcd 1048 2aca 4a75 f8c3  .9....-..H*.Ju..
```

**Listing**:

```
B8 0A39     MOV  AX, 0A39H              ; AH = 0AH, AL = '9'
B2 0A       MOV  DL, 10                 ; DL as counter value
B1 2D       MOV  CL, 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9  ; start digit repeat 45 times
        NLOOP:
CD 10       INT  10H                    ; call BIOS - write digit * CX times
48          DEC  AX                     ; decrement ASCII digit
4A          DEC  DX                     ; decrement counter value
2A CA       SUB  CL, DL                 ; reduce digit repeat value by counter
75 F8       JNZ  NLOOP                  ; loop until 0 
C3          RET                         ; return to DOS
```

[Try it online!](http://twt86.co?c=uDkKsgqxLc0QSEoo0XX4ww%3D%3D)

**Explanation**:

This uses the PC BIOS API's `INT 10H` / `0AH` function to write the ASCII char in `AL` to the screen `CX` number of times.  However, this function does not update the cursor position to the end of the output -- it just stays where it started.  In other words, the next call simply overstrikes existing characters writing over them.  Making a BIOS call to advance the cursor is expensive byte-wise.

Since going forward isn't going to work, we go backwards starting from `'9'`.  It writes `'9'` 45 times, then `'8'` 36 times, `'7'` 28 times, etc -- each time starting from the first column overwriting like so:

```
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
888888888888888888888888888888888888999999999
777777777777777777777777777788888888999999999
666666666666666666666777777788888888999999999
555555555555555666666777777788888888999999999
444444444455555666666777777788888888999999999
333333444455555666666777777788888888999999999
222333444455555666666777777788888888999999999
122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$6\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.939 bytes

```
Mcd'*_
```

[Try it online!](http://fig.fly.dev/#WyJNY2QnKl8iLCIiXQ==)

Lyxal [tried](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251799/107299) to outgolf me in my own language again.

```
Mcd'*_ # Full program
 cd    # Digits
M  '   # Map each digit string
    *  # Repeat the digit
     _ # By the number form of it
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 22 bytes

```
1:9 .|>i->show("$i"^i)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FtsMrSwV9GrsMnXtijPyyzWUVDKV4jI1IZJQNTC1AA)

prints

```
"1""22""333""4444""55555""666666""7777777""88888888""999999999"
```

Relying on the repl for printing output we can get to 17 bytes

```
~i="$i"^i;.~(1:9)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 15 bytes

```powershell
1..9|%{"$_"*$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz7JGtVpJJV5JSyW@9v9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 27 bytes

```
write(1(i:=1to 9,1to i))&\z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/tfUJSfnJpSWpSqkJuYmaeh@b@8KLMkVcNQI9PK1rAkX8FSB0RmamqqxVT9T81L@Q8A)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES8), 33 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n>9?'':''.padEnd(n,n)+f(-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7PztJeXd1KXV2vIDHFNS9FI08nT1M7TUO3Lk/zf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpuZ/AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = n =>            // n = counter, initially undefined
  n > 9 ?           // if n is greater than 9:
    ''              //   stop recursion
  :                 // else:
    ''.padEnd(n, n) //   pad an empty string with n digits n
                    //   this leaves the empty string unchanged for n undefined
    + f(-~n)        //   add the result of a recursive call with n + 1
```

#### Building in reverse order (38 bytes)

A somewhat funny alternate method is to build the string from \$n=9\$ to \$n=1\$ and pad the recursive call instead of an empty string.

By doing it this way, the required padding length is:

$$L_n=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{2}+1\right\rfloor$$

```javascript
f=(n=9)=>n?f(n-1).padEnd(n*n/2+1,n):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEAXQ5TRTadhfgfXVQsRHFHJHMtq@nXO7z1X/XOVVkBBbS5ZgF7Yb9kRQhnVx4UAg9JjmwYzgteuaF1TJUWc5KRFz@wE)

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, 69 bytes

```sql
SELECT top 9replicate(1+number,1+number)FROM spt_values WHERE'p'=type
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1211381/numbers-by-position)**

Comment: Nice code. Sometimes I wonder how well T-SQL would do in these challenges if we had a built-in number table or some equivalent to PostgreSQL's [`generate-series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-srf.html) function.

Comment: @BradC normally SQL will not win in these golfing questions even with improved features. When we use a command like **replicate(a,b)**, some of the other languages can solve problem with fewer characters than the 14 characters(minimum) it takes to call that function. The best we can do it solve the problems using a language which usually isn't optimal, and hope some people are impressed enough to up-vote those solutions.

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (`-nr`), <s>20</s> 19 characters

```
range(9)+1|"\(.)"*.
```

Thanks to:

- [2x-1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99151/2x-1) for pointing out that `range()` does *not* produce array, so operators will see separate numbers.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq -nr 'range(9)+1|"\(.)"*.'
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VcNSU9uwRilGQ09TSUvv//9/@QUlmfl5xf91dfNKc3J0M/MKSkuAnKLEct380hIgBwA)

Comment: `range(9)+1` is one byte shorter.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, @2x-1. I was never aware that parsing rules lead to that behavior.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
⭆χ⭆ιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBga6CggeJk6CpmamprW////1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs without separators. The first `StringMap` could be changed into a `for` statement for the same byte count. Explanation:

```
 χ       Predefined variable 10
⭆        Map over implicit range and join
   ι     Current index
  ⭆      Map over implicit range and join
    ι    Outer index
         Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>54</s></sup> 53 bytes

```c
i;j;f(){for(i=0;9/++i;)for(j=0;j++<i;)putchar(48+i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOss6TUOzOi2/SCPT1sDaUl9bO9NaE8TNAnKztLVtgNyC0pLkjMQiDRML7UxN69r/uYmZeUBNXECd1ly1/wE)

No delimiters between the numbers.

Comment: Would be 64 bytes with the delimiter https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOss6TUOzOi2/SCPT1sDaUl9bO9O6oLQkOSOxSMPYSFMTJJMFlMnS1rbJtNaESZlYaGdqWtf@z03MzAPq5wIaYs1V@x8A

Answer (score 3):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) <s>5</s> <s>4</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

```
@π┐
```

Uncompressed:

```
$*9N
```

Repeat 1..9 N times.

## Explanation

```
     M % Map in the range
9      % From 1 to 9
  a$   % Stringify the current counter
 a  *  % Repeat that string by the current counter
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you have the meta link to the command line flags answer? Is that related to your implementation?

Comment: @ouflak No,that's was part of the copy-pasted template.

Comment: @ouflak Why is this accepted? The 05AB1E solution is posted before this answer. You should accept that instead.

Comment: Both were 3 bytes. I just flipped a coin. I can swap them....

Comment: @ouflak The general consensus is that you [shouldn‘t accept an answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8363/66833) anyway. (Appreciate I‘m a few months late, and that you can do as you please, just spreading the consensus view)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
AÇçZ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=QcfnWg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 49 bytes

```erlang
f()->[X*(math:pow(10,X)-1)/9||X<-lists:seq(1,9)].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoAgEADAey/ZjbQ8JtE7BPEgYbVQaSp46e/mA2ZcvOxzMJe2SCHXru6AbNWqh9vmUwZfQEyDQiZwnL9PLeyilJNM7gUxzGh4vS09oE1j5GWJlB20BHn9AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
n;f(i){for(i=0;i++<9;)for(n=i;n--;)putchar(48+i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FccxDoAgDADAnVcwtiEkDg6aymNIDdrBYgi6EN@Oetux35h7V0og2FIuIGEgcW6ZCf9qEFLvCc@r8h4LjJMTpKeLVntEUbizrGiasZ8ESObpLw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
AÇîZ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QcfuWg&input=LVM)

```
NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my dumbest code golf submission ever, but here it goes

## [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), 53 bytes

```
SELECT'122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7MySxJ/f8/2NXH1TlE3dDIyNjY2AQITEHADAzMIcACCixhQP3/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/instructions.md), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╜├ìíy
```

[Try it online](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=bdc38da179&i=) or [try it online unpacked (6 bytes)](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VdAr%3AB&i=).

**Explanation (of the unpacked version):**

```python
Vd      # Push constant "0123456789"
  A     # Push 10
   r    # Pop and push a list in the range [0, 10)
    :B  # Repeat the characters in the string the integer amount of times:
        #  "122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999"
        # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [VBA] 58 bytes

```
i=1:While i<0:For x=1 to i:Debug.Print i:Next x:i=i+1:wend
```

Can be ran in Immediate

Comment: you appear to have a typo in your code (`while i<0`->`while i<10`)

Comment: You can get your code down quite a bit by using nested for loops and by using `?` in place of `debug.print` - `For i=1To 9:For j=1To i:?i:Next j,i` for 35 bytes

Comment: Oh - or better yet, if we use an approach similar to that of [Mitchell Spector's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201184/61846) we can get it down to 32 bytes as `For i=1to 45:?(3.1*i^.48)\2:Next` (or 33 bytes as `For i=1to 45:?(3.1*i ^.48)\2:Next` for 64-bit installs)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 47 bytes

```c
k;main(i){for(;9>printf("%d",i*++k);i=i*10+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/bOjcxM08jU7M6Lb9Iw9rSrqAoM68kTUNJNUVJJ1NLWztb0zrTNlPL0EDbUNO69v9/AA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

```c
main(i){for(;9>printf("%lX",(i*1L<<4*i++)/15););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOi2/SMPa0q6gKDOvJE1DSTUnQklHI1PL0MfGxkQrU1tbU9/QVNNa07r2/38A)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM08jW7M6Lb9Iw9rSrqAoM68kTUNJNUVJR1s7UytbW1vTWjNTy9bQwLr2/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [COW](https://bigzaphod.github.io/COW/), 75 bytes

```
MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMMMmoOMMMMOOmOoOOMmoOMOomoomOomOoMOomoo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S84v///fN98fJ/L3z4UwfH1zwSRIxD/f3x/M9c/Pzc8HcoEIwv7/HwA)

## Uncowed

```
moo ]    mOo <    MOo -    oom o
MOO [    moO >    MoO +    MMM =

+++++++++[>+=>=[<o>-]<<-]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brainetry](https://github.com/rojergs/brainetry), 451 bytes

This is the golfed version, ungolfed version below.

```
a b c d
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e f g h
a b c
a b c d
a b
a b c d e
a b
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c
a b c d e f g h i
a b
a b c d
a b c d e f g h i
a b c
a b c
a b c d e
a b c d e
a b c
a b c d e
a b c d e f g h
a b
a b
a b c d
a b c d e f g h
a b c
a b c d e f g
a b
a b c d e
a b
a b c d
a b c
a b c d e f g h i
a b
a b c d e f g h
a b c
a b c d
a b
a b c d e
a b c d e f g h i
a b c
a b c
a b c d
a b c
a b c d e
a b c d e f g h i
```

To try this online, follow [this link](https://repl.it/github/rojergs/brainetry) and paste the code in the `btry/replit.btry` file, then hit the green "Run" button.

Golfed version of the program below:

```
Let me explain what
is going on with this brainetry program: this
program will print the digits one to nine
and each of
those is going to
be repeated
as many times as its
own value.
Makes sense, doesn't it?
To achieve such result
we have to play
around with some nice
values in our tape.
That, and we
also have to play smart with our program pointer.
Of course
I would be delighted
to actually explain the algorithm used by this program.
The only problem
is I really
have no idea whatsoever about
what is actually going on.
Let me explain:
brainetry's instructions are a superset
of brainfuck, which means any brainfuck program can
be translated
to brainetry
and it will work.
So this is what I did, I found
a brainfuck program
that completed this task I described and
I just
translated it from brainfuck to
brainetry. Probably
there are simpler approaches
if we take
into consideration the extended operations that brainetry provides ...
However, brainetry
is still in its early stages of development
and I am
still trying to figure
out exactly
what operations to add to
brainetry. Once that set of operations becomes more well-defined
it will be
easier to harness
brainetry's power to write
computer programs. And
once that is finally done,
I will not have to steal random brainfuck programs.
```

This brainetry answer built on top of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201192/75323)

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>35</s> 26 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792)!*

```
()=>1 to 9 map(i=>s"$i"*i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCsIwEAbgvU/xUxzu3DpaSECcnDuKQ9ocEmnT2FylID57dOj@8eXBja7M/VMGxQWyqUSfcU4Jnwp4uxFxnXpZcgtiGItr9LKJ7@R163QJ8XGHKcTGNtAZJ0wuUTA214dQHwMXIP2V0t4Qc/UtPw)

Comment: This challenges allows you to return a list, so you can do [this](https://tio.run/##LcyxCsIwEAbgvU/xUzrcuTkqJCBOzh3FIW0OiaRpbE4pSJ89Orh/fGV00dV5eMioOENWleQLTjnj0wBvF5Fe0yBLOYIYxuKSvKzie3lee11Cut9gKrGxe@iMAyaXKRhb2i60u8AVyD@lMdE/IuZmq18). Also, you don't need a for loop

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 3 bytes

```
9ƛẋ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=9%C6%9B%E1%BA%8B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

-1 thanks to lyxal

Comment: [3 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=9%C6%9B%E1%BA%8B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @lyxal I frogot it worked like that :p

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus) `-i`, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
L,9Rdz£XbUBvn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HxzIoperQ4oikUKeyvP///@tm/tdNBQA)

This is making me cry. A fun feature of like 99% of stack commands is that it applies to the *whole* stack rather than the top of the stack. Very very helpful.

*-1 thanks to caird which kinda makes up for the suffering of this*

### Explained

```
L,9Rdz£XbUBvn
L,              # Start a lambda which is called implicitly by the -i flag
  9R            # Push the range [1...9]
    dz          # and zip it with itself, giving [[1, 1], [2, 2] ... [9, 9]]
      £X        # repeat x[0] by x[1] times for each x in that
        bU      # dump the contents of that onto the stack. This is a very important part because as I said, 99% of lambda stack commands map over to the whole stack, even when using quicks and stuff.
          Bv    # join each item (on the stack...) into a single integer
            n   # and join (the stack...) on newlines
```

Comment: -1 byte by replacing `€¦` with `£`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HxzIoperQ4oikUKeyvP///@tm/tdNBQA "Add++ – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 175 bytes

```
(C%;_#"~[}43WVxwuRt+*NMLmlljGig}CBAc?=vNtLr[v64m321/RzP+Ncha&&Gc#EDBX|{zx=vv:bs6p^]nllk/iVgfdvD'`N#?\\6YY3WUwvvQtPOqLo,JIHGihfCddcx>=<;:9[Y6XVl210/.-O+MLJ`&HG\[!~}|{z>=wv998rp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyLDoFQAADQb6GJCaHWhDLFolUem2iFVHpw88ytRX49zgec8ACsK/COeV7hS709UvzqGUms1SR@LSOsqshSCMBJCLyM54b2gIFKJD10SJEh0W7hy3SOKbZ/QFHBRsYjbvN5pwkDYdd6Urfd9gLAGQ9Uz3XgqGwqyMAwKE0j1qsYwkU0n92la02cToTAd3nHsROW6fe6tK5RGxW0W028UZ9hsiSa6EQw9MI3@@8sE0Oa7jxuef4D)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 24/21 bytes

w/o

```
(a=1:9).*(10 .^a.-1).÷9
```

and w/ macro:

```
a=1:9;@.a*(10^a-1)÷9
```

- array of numbers, nothing new

Comment: shouldn't the answer also include a print statement?

Comment: maybe :-) when i got the the numbers as in the decription, i took it solved...

Comment: actually evaluating it in the REPL or running w/ `julia -E` you get what you want.
(i focused to get numbers not strings as You)

Comment: Using the repl is considered as a separate language https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7844/98541 and the same applies when using a flag https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/98541

Answer (score 3):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a`, 15 bytes

```
([1-9])$1{$1-1}
```

Outputs `1` through `999999999` on separate lines. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVm0km6iUuyCpaUlaboW6zWiDXUtYzVVDKtVDHUNayGiUMkFUBoA)

#### Explanation

The `-a` flag outputs all possible matches on separate lines.

```
([1-9])$1{$1-1}
 [1-9]           Pick a digit 1 thru 9
(     )          Store it in group 1
       $1        Match group 1 again
         {    }  this many times:
          $1       Group 1 contents
            -1     minus 1
```

---

Alternate `-a` solution, also **15 bytes**:

```
([1-9])(){1,$1}
```

Outputs digits on separate lines. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVm0km6iUuyCpaUlaboW6zWiDXUtYzU1NKsNdVQMayGiUMkFUBoA)

```
([1-9])(){1,$1}
 [1-9]           Pick a digit 1 thru 9
(     )          Store it in group 1
       ()        Match empty string
         {    }  this many times:
          1,       Minimum of once
            $1     Maximum of (group 1 contents) times
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), <s>61</s> 54 bytes

```
ioiooioooiooooioooooiooooooioooooooiooooooooiooooooooo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f8/Mz8zH4TAGEJASRgFpxGM/P//AQ)

-7 bytes thanks to Bubbler.

Separating by zeros:

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 128 bytes

```
{iiiii}dcdciiccddciiicccdddciiiiccccddddciiiiicccccdddddciiiiiiccccccddddddc{i}dddccccccc{d}iiic{i}ddcccccccc{d}iic{i}dccccccccc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBDoBACANf5KNMq5GzR7JvR1o0sZd2hgQeO8@4r60qQ1kEEQFQ1d3DS1N7wGR8ecQYIvtP1yS5dLfD31l9BlUP)

By spaces:

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 159 bytes

```
{iiiii}dc{dd}iiic{ii}ddcc{dd}iic{ii}dccc{dd}ic{ii}cccc{dd}c{ii}iccccc{dd}dc{ii}iicccccc{dd}ddc{ii}iiiccccccc{dd}dddc{ii}iiiicccccccc{dd}ddddc{ii}iiiiiccccccccc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RclBEsAgCEPRE/VQTtJOWbtkPDtWCZYV74d342P9vSLc1g3CyfF98CVCTkLcgrRhKDKdIUslNcVTK1f/h7MgYgI)

Comment: [60](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f8/M7M4E4iTM5NBCIwhBJSEUXAawUj@/x8A) using shorter sequence to get to 49, and incidentally it also works in plain Deadfish. Also there's [54](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f8/Mz8zH4TAGEJASRgFpxGM/P//AQ) using `o`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4 bytes (8 nibbles)

```
,9^$`p
```

```
,9^$`p
        # implicitly map over
,9      # integers from 1 to 9      
  ^     # replicating
   `p   # the character of each 
        # by itself times
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2.0-alpha), 21 bytes

```
;=i@W>10=i+1iO*+""i i
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/v2#WyI7PWlAVz4xMD1pKzFpTyorXCJcImkgaSIsIjMiXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 21 bytes

```
" }*!@
9 : {
:(1""
""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fSaFWS9GBy1LBSqGay0rDUEmJS0np//9/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

```
Intro
9    Push 9

Loop 1
:(""    Duplicate and decrement; exit when top is 0

[9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0]
Loop 2
1:}     Use the 0 as the basis for repunit;
        append 1, copy to aux.stack  [... i "1"*i | "1"*i]
*!      Multiply i and "1"*i and print; exit when the stack is empty
{       Pull the repunit back  [... i+1 "1"*i]

@       Halt
```

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 21 bytes

```
1:#
: (*
;  !
%9_:@
"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f0EqZy0pBQ4vLWkFBkUvVMt7KgUvp//9/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

```
Loop: [... "1"*i] -> [... "1"*i "1"*(i+1)]
1     Append 1 (multiply by 10 and add 1)
:     Dup
#(    Stack size - 1 (== i+1)
*!    Multiply and print
:_9%  Test if the current repunit % 9 is 0 and exit loop if so
;:    Discard the test value and dup to increase the stack size by 1

9_:@  Halt
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>45</s> <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
9Ï^⑷:⅍*⑸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f8nB/3KOJ260etfZqPZq44/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```bash
for k in {1..9};{ echo $[10**k/9*k];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCFbITNPodpQT8@y1rpaITU5I19BJdrQQEsrW99SKzvWuvb/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 38 bytes

```
Range 1 to(9)map(i,i*(10**i-1)/9)print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z8oMS89VcFQoSRfw1IzN7FAI1MnU0vD0EBLK1PXUFPfUrOgKDOv5P9/AA)

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 47 bytes

```
Range 1 to(9)map(i,i asString repeated(i))print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z8oMS89VcFQoSRfw1IzN7FAI1MnUyGxOLikKDMvXaEotSA1sSQ1RSNTU7MAKFLy/z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 34 bytes

```python
i=0
while i<9:print(str(i:=i+1)*i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9PWgKs8IzMnVSHTxtKqoCgzr0SjuKRII9PKNlPbUFMrU/P/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 17 bytes

```
Table[,{,9},{a,}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/T8kMSknNVqnWseyVqc6Uac29n/sfwA)

thanks @att

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/T8kMSknNTpRpzpRx7IWSNbG/o/9DwA) (list of lists of digits, which based on comments should be fine)

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/T8kMSknNVqnWseyVqc6Uac29n/sfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 23 bytes

```
00000000: 3334 3232 3636 3601 0253 1030 0303 7308  3422666..S.0..s.
00000010: b080 024b 1800 00                        ...K...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYwxCsNAEAP7vEIvWHSr8@bIF1zmBwvGjV0Fv/@ykLQWjFAhJq/MY9uvc07@84KkDrkcCkUVG@iL0CiiEJ7iANTdI8LsbTT72ONnaOVIjrp6T7TBWsRNzGwt5vwC)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>37</del> <del>36</del> 35 bytes

```php
for(;10>$j=++$i;)for(;$j--;)echo$i;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKwNDexUsmy1tVUyrTXBAipZurrWmqnJGflAof//AQ)

-1 byte thanks to @Night2

Comment: Do you need the input?

Comment: Nope, removed thanks. I'm so used to using the -F option, I did it without thinking.

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKwNDexUsmy1tVUyrTXBAipZurrWmqnJGflAof//AQ)

Comment: Interesting lesson in precedence rules.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
print[i*`i`for i in range(1,10)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM68kOlMrITMhLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDUMfQQDP2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 74 bytes

```
@set s=
@for /l %%i in (1,1,9)do @call set s=%%s%%0&call echo %%s:0=%%i%%
```

Outputs on separate lines. Extends the string length by 1 and replaces the character with the current digit for each output.

The `call` commands are required so that the variable `s` is processed inside the loop instead of before parsing the loop.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>30</s> 25 bytes

```ruby
1.upto(9){|i|p 10**i/9*i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31CvtKAkX8NSs7oms6ZAwdBASytT31Irs/b/fwA)

`10**i/9` gives a number with `i` digits, all `1`s. Multiply by `i` for the required output.

Comment: 21 bytes: `1.upto(9){|i|p [i]*i}`. Going by the comments on the OP I think the output this gives is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 36 bytes

```
1a1o1a2o1a3o1a4o1a5o1a6o1a7o1a8o1a9o
```

Outputs all the numbers with no extra delimiter, using the same functionality described in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197938/91030).

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 30 bytes

```sh
repeat 9 echo ${(pl[++i][$i])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/KLUgNbFEwVIhNTkjX0GlWqMgJ1pbOzM2WiUzVrP2/38A)

The `(l[width][fill])` flag does the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 30 bytes

```
repeat a 9[repeat b a[prin a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@78otSA1sUQhUcEyGspMUkiMLijKzFNIjI39/x8A)

Well, the most obvious way to do it is the shortest in Red.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>42</s> 39 bytes

```
9 [1,b] [ dup 1array swap cycle ] map .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc0xDsIwEETRq8wBkKWUwAEQDQ2iilIsZggRYVnWGyGf3iAqul@9f5UcT2@n4/6w2@BOV854SNySi44sEHepBYWvhZr5V8lplJh0hDkjqvmkgW1bo@9W5wE9Louh@wkobzHkmmdi@A4MqbUP)

Displays a list ot lists

Answer (score 2):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula Language, 56 bytes

```
@For(x:=1;x<10;x:=x+1;@Set("o";o:@Repeat(@Text(x);x)));o
```

[image]

Formula in a multi value form field, once again showing that the only *real* use for `@For` in Notes is Code Golf!

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 47 bytes

```
O OUTPUT =DUPL(X,X)
 X =LT(X,9) X + 1 :S(O)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/31/BPzQkIDREwdYlNMBHI0InQpNLIULB1icEyLbUBDK1FQwVrII1/DW5XP1c/v8HAA)

Prints with a leading newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
9{îÄí
```

-1 byte thanks to *@maxb*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@y@vC6wy2H1/7/DwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
9{     # Loop 9 times:
  î    #  Push the 1-based loop index
   Ä   #  Do an inner loop that many times, using a single command:
    í  #   Push the total number iterations of the outer loop
       # (after the loops, the entire stack is joined together and output implicitly)
```

Comment: Without a separator, you could do [`9{îÄí`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@y@vC6wy2H1/7/DwA), where `í` pushes the loop limit within a for loop.

Comment: @maxb Ah, nice golf. Out of curiosity, why doesn't it work when the `Ä` is `{`?

Comment: @maxb It does seem to work if I add two trailing `}`: [try `9{î{í}}` online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@y@vC66sNra2v//wcA).

Comment: There are some issues with implicit block closure with nested loops. you can omit the last `}` at the end of the script if you have a single loop, but not if you have two or more nested loop blocks which are opened by `{`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 109 bytes

```
[S S S T    S S T   N
_Push_9][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_top][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_INNER_LOOP][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate_top][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_DONE_INNER_LOOP][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_INNER_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_DONE_INNER_LOOP][S N
N
_Discard_top][S N
S _Duplicate_top][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate_top][N
T   S S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_DONE_LOOP][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S S N
_Create_Label_DONE_LOOP][S N
N
_Discard_top][N
S S S T N
_Create_Label_PRINT_LOOP][T N
S T _Print_top_as_integer][N
S N
S T N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VYtBCsBACAPPySvytVIWurfCLvT5ViM9FBXiMHmuuce6j3NESEIuKdEjH1i0ADK3ktkK@2n5Z8qU5l9AtVwEI14) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Push n=9
Start LOOP:
  Duplicate top (Integer i = n)
  Start INNER_LOOP
    i = i - 1
    if(i == 0):
      Jump to DONE_INNER_LOOP
    Copy n (0-based index 1)
    Swap
    Go to next iteration of INNER_LOOP
  DONE_INNER_LOOP:
    Discard i
    n = n - 1
    if(n == 0):
      Jump to DONE_LOOP
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
DONE_LOOP:
  Discard n
  Start PRINT_LOOP:
    Print top as integer
    Go to next iteration of PRINT_LOOP
```

Funny thing is, is that outputting with the additional single leading `0` as the challenge in the Sandbox initially had, this could have been 11 bytes shorter: [try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgROIuLiADAUuMFQAY04ukDhIgBPIhigCssFKuCAciGIUlRAxkAKQUrCi//8B). xD

Comment: I'm still mulling over some kind of challenge that involves an index....

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, 85 Bytes

`@for /L %%A in (1 1 9)do @For /L %%B in (1 1 %%A)do @Call Set O=%%O%%%%A
@Echo(%O%`

TIO not available.

[image]

Comment: even longer than hardcode `@echo 122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999`

Answer (score 2):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), <sup><s>38</s></sup> 28 bytes

```
print*,(10**i/9*i,i=1,9)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vKMrMK9HS0TA00NLK1LfUytTJtDXUsdTkSs1L@f8fAA)

Edit: Turns out the `program` statement is optional, saving 10 bytes!

Comment: I'm glad somebody did a Fortran answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 8 bytes

```
aFLRL|D;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P9HNJ8inxsX6/38A)

```
aF   |   For Loop, from 0 to 10 excluding 10
  L      Push the current loop iteration to the stack
   RL    Pop the current iteration and repeat pushing the loopiterator value so many times
      D; Print the entire stack content as numeric values with the debug operation and halt
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
print([str(x)*x for x in range(1,10)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI7q4pEijQlOrQiEtv0ihQiEzT6EoMS89VcNQx9BAM1bz/38A)

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes

```cpp
for(int i=1;i<10;++i){for(int x=1;x<=i;++x){std::cout<<i;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NchBCoAgEAXQfacQ2iQR1Fan7hJjxYfUKANBPLvVord8fBzdxlxqON5vswiCv8K5zHaq4IKwM1wjRSqrP5svMA4aNPS6bSHTv/HdSCPejTJdwSjF/g5E0DmXXB4)

Started learning c++ an hour ago, tried codegolf :)

Comment: @ceilingcat so all the imports and func names must be in the code? Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzOvRCFTp8I6NzEzT0OzOi2/SMO6wlZbO9PG0MBaE8zN1K/Q1rbWjI9PKs3MKcnMiy8oLUnOSCzSyNQ2sdC0rv3/HwA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### [vJASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JASS#vJass), 126 bytes

```c
//! zinc
library q{function onInit(){integer x,y;string s="";for(1<=x<10){for(0<=y<x){s+=I2S(x);}}BJDebugMsg(s);}}
//! endzinc
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 48 bytes

```
for(x=1;x<=9;x++){console.log((x+'').repeat(x))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/jP9T8tv0ijwtbQusLG1tK6Qltbszo5P684PydVLyc/XUOjQltdXVOvKLUgNbFEo0JTs/b/fwA)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with :
`for(x=0;x++<9;){console.log((x+'').repeat(x))}`

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>93</s>, 65 bytes

```cpp
int a;void n(){int b=a;while(b){std::cout<<a;b--;}if(a++!=9)n();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBDoMgEAC/QtMLxPCAsuhfloXaTRBMRT0Q3m6tHmeSGZpnPRIdT04UVx8s56V8A07DwakIhC2zF0mq@kfXI@wfjkE6VZfijaG8FmsRnNbQ@C2x6x79S50BtOswIZ8g6m1@)

The loop work is essentially the same as the previous version, but instead its own function.

It sets the starting `digit -> 1 -> counter` then it prints digits until the counter reaches `0`. At that point it increments the digit and recalls the function until `9`.

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 93 bytes

```cpp
int main(int n){static int a=1;int b=a;if(b>9)return 0;while(b){std::cout<<a;b--;}main(a++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoMwEEWvEugmQQLtsk70LpMxbQd0lDjBRfHskbj678Hj07b5L1F9sNBcphR43TUnXMbKomZBFttA3H9XVCbTDIcXtI0DAn9sHN8uJy1ZzBOOH8/JxtZPfU9r0RAQovdw3m/YdQ7OWi8)

Don't mind the main...

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYtbCoAgEACvIkSgkFC/rXWXda1YKI2yfqSu3vNzhhmaZz0QXRl7GjfXGQ5rXDqc2ot9FFhY2AM74aVKfVikbRCs1qDW6OqawhaNQeBeYqNPzKtSPSUc3zwhPyDSa357Aw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [51](https://tio.run/##FcrBCoUgEEDR/fsK4W2UEtrWaD8SLcYpQyiNGlfRtxsu7uZw6Tz1RlT@IdKel9WEdPO14jH@MHMSXtgyzY9PlwyRBdqudYBNY3pQFZ1FcFqDunkZBkqZjUF4C9T7wBClEo@XCmpv@QA) and [59](https://tio.run/##FchLCoAgEADQqwRtFBPa5lh3GUeLgdLws4rObrR8j@5bH0R95Ehn88FyKjUHvLbOsQ4XchTy2VMWP3GdJweolF1A/ulWBKc1yFK9MZRatRbh7f0D) bytes

Comment: [50](https://tio.run/##FcjBCsMgDADQ@75C2KXSCbuO2P3GzjFNRWijaDyUsV@fY@/4qBQXicY1Ce19ZZ9y08p4PC@9JYlG8OBWkNg0XWEcmGSy7y3XKYkaXO63ADjP/gH2n2FBCM6BpdzVe4TPGF/adoxtuJdkV1l7Fadn4R8) bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <sup><s>25</s> <s>24</s></sup> 22 bytes

```
1[ddIr^9/*n1+dA>m]dsmx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98wOiXFsyjOUl8rz1A7xdEuNzalOLfi/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 50 bytes

```lisp
(loop for x from 1 to 9 do(dotimes(n x)(write x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcaxDcAgDATAVb60y5SZJ4BkCfLIWILtnVx1T7c1M6WTE42Og@YcuBDEjUIpDBt1yYujst2i/lHN/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 6 bytes

```
#9&$D$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X9lSTcVF5f9/AA)

Oh cool, another way to use cQuents!

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP 0.1](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
[![~!:~1A]%!9A?.%1M]
```

Explanation:

```
[      start of loop
!      duplicates top of stack
[      start of loop
~!:~   prints bottom stack value
1A     subtracts 1
]      end of loop
%      removes top of stack (0 from the counter in the previous loop)
!9A    diffeence between top value and 9
?.     if top 0, then terminate program
%      removes top value
1M     adds 1 to top value
]      end of loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 45 bytes

```cs
for(int j,i=0;i++<9;)for(j=i;j-->0;Write(i));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IIzOvRCFLJ9PWwDpTW9vG0loTJJhlm2mdpatrZ2AdXpRZkqqRqalp/f8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 32 bytes

```
(for[i(range 1 10)](repeat i i))
```

This results in a lists of numbers:

```
((1) (2 2) (3 3 3) (4 4 4 4) (5 5 5 5 5) (6 6 6 6 6 6) (7 7 7 7 7 7 7) (8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8) (9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 21 bytes

```
{A}1ɑee0ɑbue1søɒe1søɒ
```

Prints `122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999`.

Explanation:

```
{A}1ɑee0ɑbue1søɒe1søɒ
{A}1                  (push loop bounds, 1 to 10)
    ɑ                 (start loop)
     e                (push the current index)
      e0              (push loop bounds for current digit, 0 to index)
        ɑ             (start loop)
         bu           (DUP and CPRINT current digit)
           e1sø       (increment index)
               ɒ      (end loop)
                e1sø  (increment index)
                    ɒ (end loop)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
for i in range(10):print(str(i)*i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BA06qgKDOvRKO4pEgjU1MrU/P/fwA)

Comment: You can get your answer formatted in the standard format used on this site, over [here](https://tio.run/#python3). Just put your code in and click on the link symbol above. That will take you to another page where you will find the Code Golf format option (pasted into your clipboard). You can then just paste that into your answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll remember that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>77</s> <s>75</s> <s>73</s> <s>72</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```rust
fn main(){for k in 1..10{for j in 0..k{print!("{}",k)}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Dszotv0ghWyEzT8FQT8/QAMzNAnEN9PSyqwuKMvNKFDWUqmuVdLI1a2tr//8HAA)

And I thought Lua was verbose!

*Thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) for saving 15 bytes.*

Comment: You don't need `i`, `0..k` and `println!("{}",i)` works just fine. Then you can use a closure instead of a full program like this: `||for i in 1..10{for j in 0..k{println!("{}",k)}}`.

Comment: And returning an iterator instead of printing the result is a little shorter: https://tio.run/##FcrBCoMwDADQ@76i85TACHrtnPuLXUspLQhpFRdHwfjt3XZ88Lb9LS0Vk/1cAI/GUUx6qMJANPRIib247FfQqtATVaS/8vKJ6rQi3tu6zUW4XKE77PPsbiYBUliYYxBrx1cMo5sm@NXL2b4

Comment: @ovs, Wow. This is the first time I've coded anything in Rust (we've just adopted it at my workplace), so it's clear I've got a lot to learn. I'm still trying to wrap my head around how the closures work. I'm using `print!` instead. That seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 50 bytes

```
+[>+<+++++]+++++++++[>-->+[<.>>+<-]>[<+>-]<<+++<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO9pO20YbBGK1YSDaTlfXTjvaRs8OKKcbaxdto22nG2sDUgbk/v8PAA)

Assumes byte cells; does not go out of bounds to left.

Answer (score 2):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/), 222 bytes

```
THE NUMERICAL I/O RULES
i saw a digit,o yes
o,again,i saw a number;too many
i do the I/O rules,i get a repeat
i now count to zeros
o,from one right to nine,i do digits,e.t.c
seldom a newline,since i know i am swayed not to
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?NY5LCsJAEET3OUUdYIgHcCUSUPADfg7QZtrYmHTLzIQQLx8nAdf16lXddhVO92N12W83B@xXZ1zuh@paCCINIHhpJDnDyLEwRw2Jun@mfffgsE5m6EjH3PGG9OJFE/qWY0YbThkN/GFKmVAbUFuvCcnw5WCz9hmsgykjSPNaEhVlt/iWA9Fxmcq6iNz6jOZpHtoZiaI1Q/CevQLqEAca2eed2TNND/I/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
mod´Rḣ9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzc/5dCWoIc7Flv@/w8A)

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
mdg´Ṙḣ9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzcl/dCWhztnPNyx2PL/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
９｛：ŗ×］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE5JXVGRjVCJXVGRjFBJXUwMTU3JUQ3JXVGRjNE,v=8)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>29</s> 24 bytes

<sup>Saved 5 bytes thanks to Taylor Raine</sup>

```
=REPT(ROW(1:9),ROW(1:9))
```

`ROW(1:9)` returns an array of the numbers 1 through 9 so the `REPT()` function repeats each of those numbers itself-many times.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can make this shorter by dropping the `Let` and using `Row(1:9)` instead - `=REPT(ROW(1:9),ROW(1:9))`

Answer (score 2):

## APOL, 21 bytes

`ⅎ(9 p(*(t(∈) ∈)))`

Comment: Could you provide a link to an interpreter for APOL?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing https://replit.com/@GingerIndustries/APOL

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
,tX,t
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZLdUoidEogbKgQTAoA)

#### Explanation

```
,t     Range(10)
  X    String-repeat (itemwise)
   ,t  Range(10)
```

That is, for each number in `[0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]`, repeat it a number of times equal to itself. The result is the list `[""; 1; 22; 333; 4444; 55555; 666666; 7777777; 88888888; 999999999]`, which is by default concatenated together and printed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 21 bytes

```
l=[1...9]
l10^l/9-l/9
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dwtxa2wo4t)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/95dpilouxx)

Uses the following formula for the \$n\$th number:
$$\frac{10^n-1}9\times n$$
`[1,22,333,4444,55555,666666,7777777,88888888,999999999]` is the value of the list in the second line.

Made it look "obfuscated" for fun but it's really just the same as:

```
l=[1...9]
l(10^l-1)/9
```

which is also 21 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$7\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 5.762 bytes

```
Ma9'*+D
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJNYTknKitEIiwiIl0=)

### Explained

```
Ma9'*+D
Ma9'    # To each item n in the range [1, 9]
    *+D # Repeat the stringified n, n times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 15 bytes

```
(#1{#1} ! ){10}
```

Outputs space-separated runs of digits, with a leading and a trailing space. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboW6zWUDauVDWsVFBU0qw0NaiGiUEmYIgA)

#### Explanation

Spaces are replaced with underscores for clarity.

```
(#1{#1}_!_){10}
           {10}  Repeat 10 times
(         )      and store as group 1 after each match:
 #1                Length of previous match of group 1
   {#1}            repeated (length of previous match of group 1) times
       _           followed by a space
        !          Or, if that failed because there was no previous match of group 1,
         _         just a space
```

The first match of group 1 is a space, which has length 1, so the second match is one 1 followed by a space, which has length 2, so the third match is two 2's followed by a space, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 31 bytes

```
+^{{D^(]<)PN][}:(+++[]]]>)N^-[}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiK157e0ReKF08KVBOXVt9OigrKytbXV1dPilOXi1bfSIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

Beats the naive solution (`+P+PP+PPP`... and so on for 54 bytes) by 23 bytes.

Outputs individual digits separated by newlines

Breakdown:

```
+^{{D^(]<)PN][}:(+++[]]]>)N^-[}  full program

+^                               initialize r1 to be 1
                                 r2 is already initialized to 0
  {                           }  repeat
    D^(  )     :(        )       until r1
                 +++[]]]>        fails to be less than 9
   {          }                    repeat
    D^(  )                         until r1
       ]<                          fails to be more than r2
    D     P                          print r1
           N][                       increment r2
                                   end repeat
                          N^       increment r1
                          N -[     set r2 to 0
                                 end repeat
```

Comment: this 25 byter takes n and outputs the number n*(n 1s in a row): `U({D+^-)DD]P:]]]]]]]]]][}`. I don't think I can iterate from 1-9 with just 5 bytes though...

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 43 bytes

```
:-between(1,9,N),between(1,N,_),\+write(N).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/30o3KbWkPDU1T8NQx1LHT1MHwfXTidfUidEuL8osSdXw09T7/x8A)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/30o3ryTDUMNPJ14nXlMnKbWkPDU1T8NQx08nQlOnvCizJFXDT1Mnws5C7/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [yup](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/yup), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
0e:{~:{~:#~0e-}0e--:0ee00e--|00e--e0e-~-}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##qywt@P/fINWqug6ElOsMUnVrgVjXyiA11QDEqAGTqUCiTrf2/38A)

**Explanation:**

```python
0e           # Push 1 (push 0; pop and push exp(0))
  :          # Duplicate it
   {         # Loop while the top of the stack is >0 (without popping):
    ~        #  Swap the top two values on the stack
     :       #  Duplicate the top
      {      #  Inner loop while the top of the stack is >0 (without popping):
       ~     #   Swap the top two values on the stack
        :    #   Duplicate the top
         #   #   Pop and print it as number
       ~     #   Swap the top two values on the stack back
        0e-  #   Decrease it by 1 (push 0; pop and push exp(0); subtract)
      }      #  Stop the inner loop if the top of the stack is <=0 (without popping)
       0e--  #  Increase the current value by 1 (using the 0 that was still on the
             #  stack as: push 0 → exp(0)=1 → 0-1=-1 → --1=+1)
       :     #  Duplicate the top again
        0ee00e--|00e--e0e-
             #  Push 9.107... (see below)
         ~   #  Swap the top two values again
          -  #  Subtract the current value from the 9.107...
   }         # Stop the outer loop if the top of the stack is <=0 (without popping)
             # (which it will be once we've reached 10)

0ee00e--|00e--e0e- # Push 9.107...:
0                  #  Push 0        - STACK: 0
 e                 #  exp(0)        - STACK: 1
  e                #  exp(1)        - STACK: 2.718...
   0               #  Push 0        - STACK: 2.718...,0
    0              #  Push 0        - STACK: 2.718...,0,0
     e             #  exp(0)        - STACK: 2.718...,0,1
      -            #  Subtract      - STACK: 2.718...,-1
       -           #  Subtract      - STACK: 3.718...
        |          #  ln(3.718...)  - STACK: 1.313...
         0         #  Push 0        - STACK: 1.313...,0
          0        #  Push 0        - STACK: 1.313...,0,0
           e       #  exp(0)        - STACK: 1.313...,0,1
            -      #  Subtract      - STACK: 1.313...,-1
             -     #  Subtract      - STACK: 2.313...
              e    #  exp(2.313...) - STACK: 10.107...
               0   #  Push 0        - STACK: 10.107...,0
                e  #  exp(0)        - STACK: 10.107...,1
                 - #  Subtract      - STACK: 9.107...
```

Answer (score 2):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <sup><s>59</s></sup> <sup><s>58</s></sup> 57 bytes (thanks ouflak!)

```fs
for i=1 to 9 do String.replicate i (string i)|>printf"%s"
```

or

```fs
for i=1 to 9 do printf"%s"(String.replicate i (string i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Py2/SCHT1lChJF/BUiElXyG4pCgzL12vKLUgJzM5sSRVIVNBoxgsppCpWWNXAGSVpCmpFiv9/w8A)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This is a nice submission. As this is a golfing challenge though, white space is among your first enemies, [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Py2/SCHT1lChJF/BUiElXyG4pCgzL12vKLUgJzM5sSRVIVNBI7PGrhgsrFljVwCkS9KUVIuV/v8HAA). It does not matter if the program exits with an error or slew of warnings as long as it meets the criteria of the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 3 bytes

```
9ƛY
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCI5xptZIiwiIiwiIiwiMy40LjEiXQ==)

Edit, the three byter is valid

Comment: This is great. Would you provide a link to the 'lists of digits' solution, maybe here in the comments? It might actually meet the conditions of the challenge which are pretty broad as far as the output is concerned.

Comment: it's just `9ƛY`

Comment: Yes! That's definitely within the output rules.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 9 bytes

```
▽:+@0.⇡10
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4pa9OitAMC7ih6ExMAo=)

Answer (score 1):

## [mlochbaum/BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 7 bytes

```
⥊˜¨1+↕9
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=4qWKy5zCqDEr4oaVOQ==)

### Explanation

```
⥊˜¨1+↕9
     ↕9 range from 0 to 8
   1+   add 1 to each
  ¨     for each element n,
⥊˜      replicate n times
```

Comment: Alternative 7 bytes (with different format): `∾⥊˜¨↕10`. Also, `⥊˜¨↕10` (6 bytes) could be used if a leading empty list is fine (it probably is).

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 32 or 37 bytes

This code needs an `EOF` at the prompt, or a file with an empty line.

```
{for(;++i<10;)print(10^i-1)/9*i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMNaWzvTxtDAWrOgKDOvRMPQIC5T11BT31Irs/b/fy4A)

To substitute the input, one can use the `BEGIN` pattern, adding 5 more bytes to the code.

```
BEGIN{for(;++i<10;)print(10^i-1)/9*i}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 50 bytes

```js
_=>{for(i=0;++i<10;)console.log((''+i).repeat(i))}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

```
9 [1,b] [ dup <array> ] map .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeUmJeeWqyQnVqUl5qjkFhUlFhZrFCcWliampcMFC8oSi0pqSwoyswrUbD@b6kQbaiTFKsQrZBSWqBgA1ZtpxALNKlAQe//fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## A0A0, 46 bytes

```
O122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999
```

Literally prints the example output. I'd be very surprised if you can get something smaller in A0A0. The first `O` outputs the number following it and the number following it is the output. The language specification does not state any restriction on the size of the number, just "signed integer", so this works. (Although an interpreter may not handle this correctly, because this is a 147 bit number and not every language may support numbers that large.)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 17 bytes

```
seq(I(₁₀^(I)-1)/9,I,1,9
```

Output is stored in `Ans` as a list and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 37 bytes

```lua
for i=1,9 do print((""..i):rep(i))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPWUMdSISVfoaAoM69EQ0NJSU8vU9OqKLVAI1NTMzUv5f//xOS0qipHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pure [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 27 bytes

```
eval ';s+=1;<<<$[s*'{1..9}]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuha7U8sScxTUrYu1bQ2tbWxsVKKLtdSrDfX0LGtjISqgCmEaAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](https://golfscript.com/golfscript/), 9 bytes

```
10,{.`*}/
```

### Explanation

```
     /  # for each element in...
     10,{ # 0-9
     . # duplicate it
     ` # stringify it
     * # push to the stack the stringified version of the number, repeated that many times
    }  # end block
       # implicitly output the stack
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39BAp1ovQatW//9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 28 bytes

```
1:\   >~1+:a=?;!
n$>:?!v1-$:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39AqRkFBwa7OUNsq0dbeWpErT8XOyl6xzFBXxer/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
ɳąĐƖ*ǰ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5OYjrUcmHJumdXzD//8ZqTk5@QolGalFqQA)

```
ɳ           pushes string containing all digits ("0123456789")
 ą          converts to ąrray of characters
  Đ         Đuplicates on stack
   Ɩ        casts top of stack to array of Ɩntegers
    *       string multiplication
     ǰ      ǰoin with no delimiter; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `N`, \$ 8 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
9R1+eDJ*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6Fissgwy1U128tCBcqOgCKA0A)

##### Explanation

```python
9R        # Push range(0, 9)
  1+      # Add one to each
    e     # To each number:
     D    #  Duplicate
      J   #  Cast to string
       *  #  Repeat that many times
          # N flag joins by newlines
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 50 bytes

```
_=>'122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999' // 50
_=>eval("for(s='',i=0;i<11;s+=''.padEnd(++i,i))s") // 50
n=>eval("for(s='';(n=-~n)<11;s+=''.padEnd(n,n))s") // 50
_=>'123456789'.replace(/(\d)/g,(d,i)=>d.repeat(i)) // 50
```

Try it:

```js
f1=_=>'122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999' // 50
f2=_=>eval("for(s='',i=0;i<10;s+=''.padEnd(++i,i))s") // 50
f3=n=>eval("for(s='';(n=-~n)<11;s+=''.padEnd(n,n))s") // 50
f4=_=>'123456789'.replace(/(\d)/g,(d,i)=>d.repeat(i)) // 50

console.log(f1());
console.log(f2());
console.log(f3());
console.log(f4());
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 15 bytes

```
∵(⋕/⊂∵°⋕↯).+1⇡9
```

[Pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4oi1KOKLlS_iioLiiLXCsOKLleKGrykuKzHih6E5Cg==)

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)’s type system, 94 bytes

```typescript
type F<N extends 1[]=[1],L=N["length"]>=L extends 10?[]:[...{[_ in keyof N]:L},...F<[...N,1]>]
```

[Try it at the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAOShAHsCA7AJgZygRgG0BdAXkP2IBoAZUhQgIgBtMBzYAC0eID5SayNJlwEADAH4SALkIA6BQG9CAfSgBLDFADWEEAHsAZlATFpNAL5UFc+PIUIqlXsQCwAKA+hIUAF5RSWA8AemCocIA9CQ8gA)

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/yasepl-esolang), 24 bytes

```
=a$`1=b)""ſa;b,a<!+}4,9
```

### explanation (in pseudocode)

```
=a$`1=b)""ſa;b,a<!+}4,9          packed
=a$                              a = 1
   `1            !+}4,9          for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
     =b)""ſa;b,a<                  print(str(a).repeat(a))
```