# Let's start with a brainy quote

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

The challenge today is to write a program that outputs a known proverb, `Where there is a will, there is a way.`, that means if someone is determined to do something, he will find a way to accomplish it regardless of obstacles.

### Output

It has to be exactly the same, including the space bar and punctuation and excluding the newline at the end.

```
Where there is a will, there is a way.
```

You may not use `Where` `there` `is` `a` `will` or `way` anywhere in the source.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer per language wins.

Comment: Looks like specific question titles can cause CAPTCHA popups.

Comment: @Deusovi Should I use the `rosetta-stone` tag?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Let's put aside for a moment the fact that this is probably a dupe. Can you confirm that there must be no `"a"` at all in the source code, since this is a single-character forbidden string?

Comment: We've had a lot of challenges before about printing strings without using them or parts of them, and I think the methods for doing this have been pretty thoroughly mined out. Not something I'd expect a new poster to know, of course.

Comment: I edited the last line, so it's more in line with the usual wording. Feel free to change it back if you want.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Awesome challenge nonetheless!

Comment: Several of the entries seem to be printing a newline at the end (I'm looking at the TIO output).  Is that permitted or not?  (The challenge does say: "Excluding the newline at the end.")

Comment: I've rephrased the challenge so it's simpler to understand and shows more effort put into making it.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk  I've removed the added phrase "in any case", since the rules of the challenge should not change after answers have been posted.

Comment: Possibly I may have overlooked that, good catch.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

-2 thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

```
…€Ç€ˆ€…“‚Ã ÿ€§, ÿƒƒ.“.ª
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyR01rDrcDidNtQALEb5jzqGHW4WaFw/uBAoeW6wAZxyYdm6QHlNA7tOr/fwA)

### Older version, 24 bytes

```
“‚Ã€Ç€ˆ€…€§,€Ç€ˆ€…ƒƒ.“.ª
```

-1 thanks to @petStorm

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcRw2zDjc/alpzuB1InG4DEo8algHJQ8t10EWPTTo2SQ@oRe/Qqv//AQ)

Comment: You posted exactly when I finished my own 05AB1E solution... it's shorter anyway.

Comment: [Sentence capitalization is a built-in.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcRw2zDjc/alpzuB1InG4DEo8algHJQ8t10EWPTTo2SQ@oRe/Qqv//AQ)

Comment: I tried it, I wonder why it didn't work...

Comment: [Here's mine](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcR01rDrcDidNtQOJRwzKg0KEdjxrmAXmHlusAGccmHZuk96hh1uFFjxrmguhmIH104ek5hzcc3vv/PwA).

Comment: Do you have any idea why [this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOcR01rDrcDidNtQOJRwzKgkAtIuGHW4WaFw/uBgoeW6wAZxyYdm6QHlNA7tOr/fwA) doesn't capitalize correctly?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes, you're using the 05AB1E (legacy) version instead of new 05AB1E version. In the legacy version, that builtin didn't exist yet. [Your program works just fine in the Elixir rewrite version.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcR01rDrcDidNtQOJRwzKgkAtIuGHW4WaFw/uBgoeW6wAZxyYdm6QHlNA7tOr/fwA)

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyR01rDrcDidNtQALEb5jzqGHW4WaFw/uBAoeW6wAZxyYdm6QHlNA7tOr/fwA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

```javascript
_=>`W\here${s=' t\here i\s \x61 w'}ill,${s}\x61y.`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i4hPCYjtShVpbrYVl2hBMxWyIwpVoipMDNUKFevzczJ0QFK1oL4lXoJ/5Pz84rzc1L1cvLTNdI0NDX/AwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 38 bytes

```
Wht8ll,t0y.
t
 th 8s 0 w
h
here
T`d`l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKzyjxCInR6fEoFKPq4RLoSRDwaJYwUChnCuDKyO1KJUrJCElIef/fwA) Explanation:

```
Wht8ll,t0y.
```

Insert `Wht1ll,t0y.`.

```
t
 th 8s 0 w
```

Expand to `Wh th 8s 0 w8ll, th 8s 0 w0y.`.

```
h
here
```

Expand to `Where there 8s 0 w8ll, there 8s 0 w0y.`.

```
T`d`l
```

Transliterate the digits to letters, so as to avoid having the words `is` or `a` in the code.

Comment: @Leo's Retina Kolmogorov golfer came up with a similar solution that is also 38 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>87 78 75 ...</s> 59 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to @my pronoun is monicareinstate!*

*-3 bytes thanks to @Arnauld!*

*+1 byte for forgetting the period*

*-3 bytes thanks to @petStorm!*

*-3 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!*

```c
f(){printf("W\here%sill,%1$s\x61y."," t\here i\s \x61 w");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQyk8JiO1KFW1ODMnR0fVUKU4psLMsFJPSUdJoQQso5AZU6wAElQoV9K0rv2fm5iZp6GpUK0ANMRaofY/AA)

Comment: 77 and valid: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQyk8I1VJqShVoSQjtUhJKVUhU0mpWEE1WaE8M0dJKUcHJA6Wh4urJlcq6ViaQ5Cmde3/3MTMPA1NhWoFoLHWCrX/AQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQyk8I1VJqShVoSQjtUhJKVUhU0mpWCGmwsxQoTwzR0kpRwckA1aBJAMiK5U0rWv/5yZm5mloKlQrAM20Vqj9DwA)

Comment: You can abuse some undefined escape codes (stolen from Arnauld's answer). [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/1@rwlZJoSQmI7UoVSEzplghpsLMUKFcyTpNQ7O6oCgzryRNQykcLK1anJmTo6NaDFJRqaekU6FToWld@z83MTNPQ1OhWgGow1qh9j8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 102 bytes

```apl
x←⎕UCS 97
⎕←('⎕'⎕R'')'Wher⎕e ther⎕e i⎕s ',x,' w⎕ill, t⎕here i⎕s ',x,' w⎕ay.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@JR24RHfVNDnYMVLM25gCwgX0MdSINwkLq6pnp4RmoRkJ2qUAJjZALJYgV1nQoddYVyIDszJ0dHoQTIACrAlE2s1FP//x8A)

## Explanation:

```apl
x←⎕UCS 97
```

Define x and store ASCII (⎕UCS) 97

```apl
⎕←
```

Print (not be confused with define ⎕)

```apl
('⎕'⎕R'')
```

⎕Replace '⎕' to empty string

```apl
'Wher⎕e ther⎕e i⎕s ',x,' w⎕ill, t⎕here i⎕s ',x,' w⎕ay.'
```

will be

```apl
'Where there is ',x,' will, there is ',x,' way.'
```

And

```apl
...',x,'...
```

Means Followed by "a" followed by other string

Or if you want everything in one code then

```apl
x←⎕UCS 97     x = "a"
⎕←('⎕'⎕R'')'Wher⎕e ther⎕e i⎕s ',x,' w⎕ill, t⎕here i⎕s ',x,' w⎕ay.'
⎕←                                                                        Print
                                                                 ' w⎕ay.' The string 'w⎕ay.'
                                                                ,          Join
                                                               x           "a"
                                                              ,            Join
                                      ' w⎕ill, t⎕here i⎕s '              The string ' w⎕ill, t⎕here i⎕s '
                                   ,x,                                     Join, "a", Join
            'Wher⎕e ther⎕e i⎕s '                                         The string 'Wher⎕e ther⎕e i⎕s '
  ('⎕'⎕R'')                                                               Replace '⎕' to Empty String
```

Comment: 44 bytes: `⍞←'W',⎕C'_'⎕R' THERE IS A W'⊢'HERE_ILL,_AY.'`

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, <s>54</s> <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```bash
echo WHERE "THERE IS A w"{ILL\,,Ay}|tr ?-V\\n _-v.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18h3MM1yFVBKQRMeQYrOCqUK1V7@vjE6Og4VtbWlBQp2OuGxcTkKcTrlun9/w8A)

---

---

If we're allowed to print a newline at the end, as several other entries appear to be doing, then:

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, 47 bytes

```bash
echo WHERE "THERE IS A w"{ILL\,,Ay.}|tr ?-V _-v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18h3MM1yFVBKQRMeQYrOCqUK1V7@vjE6Og4VurV1pQUKdjrhinE65b9/w8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 1170 bytes (by hand)

I wrote this one by averaging the ascii value of every character in the saying. I then pushed the value (87) to the stack. Then on stack 2 I pushed the ascii value of the next character - 87 then added 87. The numbers were all coded by [this](https://brain-flak.github.io/integer/) program

```
((((((()()()){}()){}){}())){}{})<>([(((()()()()()){}){}){}()])((((()()()()){}){}()){}<>({})<>)((()()()()()){}<>({})<>)((((()()()()){}){}){}<>({})<>)([((()()()()()){}){({}[()])}{}]<>({})<>)((()()()()()){}<>({})<>)([((()()()()()){}){({}[()])}{}]<>({})<>)((((()()()){}()){}){}<>({})<>)((((()()()){})){}{}<>({})<>)([((()()()()()){}){({}[()])}{}]<>({})<>)(((()()()){}()){}<>({})<>)(((((()()())){}{})){}{}<>({})<>)(((()()()){}()){}<>({})<>)(((()()()()){}){}()<>({})<>)((((()()()){}()){}){}()<>({})<>)([((()()()()()){}){({}[()])}{}]<>({})<>)([((((()()()){}()){})){}{}()]<>({})<>)((((()()()){}())){}{}<>({})<>)((((()()()){}())){}{}<>({})<>)((((()()()){})){}{}<>({})<>)((((()()()()){}){}){}<>({})<>)([((()()()()()){}){({}[()])}{}]<>({})<>)((()()()()()){}<>({})<>)([((()()()()()){}){({}[()])}{}]<>({})<>)((((()()()){}()){}){}<>({})<>)((((()()()){})){}{}<>({})<>)([((()()()()()){}){({}[()])}{}]<>({})<>)(((()()()){}()){}<>({})<>)(((((()()())){}{})){}{}<>({})<>)(((()()()){}()){}<>({})<>)(((()()()()){}){}()<>({})<>)((((()()()){}()){}){}()<>({})<>)([((()()()()()){}){({}[()])}{}]<>({})<>)((((()()()){}())()){}{}<>({})<>)(((()()()){}()){}<>({})<>)(((()()()()){}){}()<>({})<>)(<>{}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMCNEFQs7oWTEBoIAlk2thpRMMVQBXBlMRqaiBJwTVW1wI1gbVqomlEFtfAMBAhG41hIVAmGmQh0EmxhE0nXj@mz7HLQkKDLBtQLEA1HSoHCWk0G/DqRAty/D5ClifW3dFYTAI7EKgUp22YPiBSFqfcaOoYlKkDzRwN6rjOxg6kUpPr////uo4A)

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 640 bytes (using text generator found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157665/63187))

This was produced using an answer to a challenge I maded a while back.

```
(((((<(((<(<((<<((((<(<((((((((<(<(((((()(()(()()()()()){}){}){})(()(((()()[]){}){}){})({}){})[(((()[]){}){}){}])(()(()()[]){}){})>(((([]){}){}){})()((()([])({}){}){}){})>(((()()[]){}){})()(()((()()()[]){}){}){})[()()[]])[()((([]){}){}){}])(()(()[]){})({}){})()()[])[()[]])()()())((()()()){}){})>((()[]){})((()()()){}){})>(((()[])({}){}){}))[()()()])(()(()()()){}){})[()(()([]){}){}])>(()((()()[]){}){})>(()()()()()()()()()[])()()(()()()[])({}){})[(()()()()()){}])>(()()()()()()[])()(()()()()()()()[]){})>((()([]){}){})[()((()()()){}){}])()()())((()()()){}){})>([])()(()[]){})()((()()()){}){})[()((()()()){}){}])()()())[()((()()()()){}){}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVFJDoMwDPyOc@AHEVLfYflAD5WqVj1wrfp2l3iLEwQJYGbsydjc9@35WR7v7cUM7apyH89awUOAISy2bZXvz7bgwiAlVF8oVCIodAJcW85QW0TvgCAwz8uF5kkNZQFUgCQYtP14hSB0GoBaY/25bjrcq86MUN2sGoBCaWjJmvZmftboIQ@kzAvNWP@KAed/QlOxlp2kvKE@GoSpr@tBuKZNY064VkpM55h5uf0B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 65 bytes

```erlang
z()->"W\here"++[" t\here i\x73 \x61 w"++X||X<-["ill,","\x61y."]].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/W/SkNT104pPCYjtShVSVs7WkmhBMxWyIypMDdWiKkwM1QoB0pE1NRE2OhGK2Xm5Ogo6SiBxCv1lGJj9f7nJmbmaUTHairo2nEpAEFmvlVaeVFmSaoG0GxNvf8A)

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 65 bytes

This simply employs the almighty hard-coding.

```erlang
z()->"W\here t\here i\x73 \x61 w\ill, t\here i\x73 \x61 w\x61y.".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/W/SkNT104pPCYjtShVoQRCZcZUmBsrxFSYGSqUx2Tm5OhglQCSlXpKev9zEzPzNKJjNRV07bgUgCAz3yqtvCizJFUDaLam3n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>95</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```python
exit("W""here%sill,%s\x61y."%((" t""here i""s \x61 w",)*2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RDKVxJKSO1KFW1ODMnR0e1OKbCzLBST0lVQ0NJoQQipZCppFSsAJJQKFfS0dQy0tT8/x8A)

-35 bytes thanks to newbie and petStorm. -1 byte thanks to newbie and petStorm.

I completely forgot that % did string formatting.

Comment: [porting my C answer, 60 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9JWSaFESSkjtShVIVNJqVghpsLMUKFciSu1IrNEQykcIqWkXamtlJmTowNmgJRU6ilp/v8PAA)

Comment: Python has string formatting as well. [Same length, 60 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9JWSaFESSkjtShVIVNJqVghpsLMUKFciSu1IrNEQykcIqVanJmTo6NaDJKs1FNS1ajUqdTU/P8fAA)

Comment: On Python 3.8 you can save a single byte using the walrus operator. [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7Uis0RDKVxJKSO1KFW1ODMnR0e1OKbCzLBST0lVo9LKVkmhBCKpkKmkVKwAklIoV9Kp1NT8/x8A)

Comment: Aww, I completely forgot % did formatting

Comment: No need for walrus operator tho. [59 bytes, python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7Uis0RDKVxJKSO1KFW1ODMnR0e1OKbCzLBST0lVQ0NJoQQipZCppFSsAJJQKFfS0dQy0tT8/x8A)

Comment: Works in [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RDKVxJKSO1KFW1ODMnR0e1OKbCzLBST0lVQ0NJoQQipZCppFSsAJJQKFfS0dQy0tT8/x8A) as well.

Comment: 57 bytes using f-strings [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8JWSaFESSkjtShVIVNJqVghpsLMUKFciSu1IrNEQylcKQ0sV11Rm5mTowOkQPKVekqa//8DAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 241 bytes

```
++++++++++[>+++++++++>++++++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++>+++<<<<<<-]>---.>++++.>+.>++++.<.>>>++.<<++.<<.>.>--.<.>>>.<<<<+.>>+.>>.<<<----.>>>.<<++++.<<.+++..>>>++++.>.<<---.<<----.>++++.>--.<.>>>.<<<<+.>>+.>>.<<<----.>>>.<<++++.<.>++.>++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYxBCoBADAMfJM0LSj8iHlQQRPAg@P7aprqeBAubzpYk0zGu@3LOm3vXpreGL31gcYpyZDARAa@hNyjMLLdSYAhXXZGp8KWXH2GeXFlFrmrIUtCDx1nH/3WZ4HO/AA)

Could use some golfing but it's getting late.

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 44 bytes

```
iWh t wi²l, t w97y.Ót/&h i115 97
Óh/here
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzM8Q6FEoTzz0KYcHRBDzNK8Uk/68OQSfbUMhUwxQ0NTBaAQ1@HJGfoZqUWp//8DAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 6957 6820 7420 7769 b26c 2c20 7420 7716  iWh t wi.l, t w.
00000010: 3937 792e 1bd3 742f 2668 2069 1631 3135  97y...t/&h i.115
00000020: 2016 3937 0dd3 682f 6865 7265             .97..h/here
```

I suspect this can be shorter, but I'm a bit rusty with V.

---

Yes it can be shorter!

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 42 bytes

```
i.yaw 97 si ereht ,lliw 97 si e erehWæ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P1OvMrFcQczSXKE4UyG1KDWjREEnJycTIcQHFg2XPrzs/38A)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 692e 7961 7720 1639 3720 7369 2065 7265  i.yaw .97 si ere
00000010: 6874 202c 6c6c 6977 2016 3937 2073 6920  ht ,lliw .97 si 
00000020: 650e 2065 7265 6857 1be6                 e. erehW..
```

---

## V or vim, either one, 38 bytes

```
iwHERE THERES A WILL, THERES A WAY.V~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P7PcwzXIVSEERAYrOCqEe/r46CBxHSP1pMPq/v8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 341 bytes

```
{{i}d}dddc{i}{i}dddcdddc{i}iiic{d}dddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}dd}iiiic{d}ddcdddc{i}iiic{d}dddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}iiic{i}c{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dddd}iiiiic{{d}iiii}dddddc{{i}d}dddc{d}ddddciiicc{{d}iiii}ddddc{d}ddc{{i}dd}iiiic{d}ddcdddc{i}iiic{d}dddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}iiic{i}c{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dddd}iiiiic{{d}iiii}dddddc{{i}d}dddc{d}{d}ddc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}iii}dddddc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZAxDoAwDANfxKNQDcIzY5S3hzQxEmxsTLbja1MV24qd57FEmNHhAEaa6dMpkRymLjWj56CYGVR@oNElXY2g0r6K95meqW2uBGNCb0r7/3iRNtePPWGxERc)

Not as bad as usual!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 26 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`ï,ÀnØi,ÌÀÎsn°y.`qn
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=YO8AACzAAYluhNhpLMzAzg9zboSweS5gcW4)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
“ḅṫ!Ḃḃ0ʋŀɼYẆḊỵ2Ƭqɦ⁷-&Y£z»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//4oCc4biF4bmrIeG4guG4gzDKi8WAybxZ4bqG4biK4bu1Msasccmm4oG3LSZZwqN6wrv//w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üx♦r i0c@9lc¡
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=817804722069306340396c63ad&i=&a=1)